# Prove that $(ma, mb) = |m|(a, b)\ $ [GCD & LCM Distributive Law]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to prove that $(ma, mb) = $|$m$|$(a, b)$ , where $(ma, mb)$ is the greatest common divisor between $ma$ and $mb$.

My thoughts:

If $(ma, mb) = d$ , then $d$|$ma$ and $d$|$mb$ → $d$|$max + mby$ → $d$|$m(ax+by)$. This implies that $d$|$m$ or $d$|$(ax+by)$. This is the same as  $d$|$m$ or $d$|$a$ and $d$|$b$, so $d$|$m$ or $d$|$(a,b)$. This is the same as $d$|$m|$ or $d|(a,b)$, so $d$|$|m|(a,b)$.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below are sketches of six proofs of the **GCD Distributive Law** $\rm\:(ax,bx) = (a,b)x\:$ by various approaches: Bezout's identity,  the universal gcd property, unique factorization, and induction.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for naturals $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ na\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = nax + kbx,\ \,$ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

Readers familiar with ideals may note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c \approx gcd(a,b)$. This proof fails in non-Bezout domains like $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y],\,$  e.g. $\,(x,2) = 1 = (x,y)\,$ but the gcds cannot be written as linear combinations, else $\, 1 = x\,f(x,y) + y\,g(x,y)\Rightarrow\,1=0\,$ by evaluating at $\,x=0=y.\,$ But the next proof works fine there  (or in any gcd domains).

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we have

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ \approx\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D\ \,$ [$c\approx d :=  c,d\,$ [associate:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863228/242) $\,c\mid d\mid c$]

**Proof** $\rm\quad\! c\mid(a,b)\!\!\overset{\rm def\!\!}\iff c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \!\!\overset{\rm def\!\!}\iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x$

where $\,\rm x\mid ax,bx\ \smash{\overset{\rm def}\Rightarrow}\ x\mid (ax,bx).\,$ Thus $\rm\,(a,b) \approx (ax,bx)/x,\,$ since they divide each other by above.  We used the [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242) (it often simplifies proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832).

---

**Or** by [this Remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2127538/242) it's case $\,m = abc\,$ in  $\,(m/a,m/b) = m/{\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ for $\,m\,$ being any common multiple of $a,b;\,$ or, expressed equivalently $\,\gcd(a',b') = {\rm lcm}(a,b)'\,$ by cofactor *duality*.

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$\begin{eqnarray} \min(a+x,\,b+x) &\,=\,& \min(a,b) + x\\
\rm expt\ analog\ of\ \ \ \gcd(a \,* x,\,b \,* x)&=&\rm \gcd(a,b)\,*x\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\,\le,\,$ and using the universal property of min instead of that of gcd, i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b)\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \,|\,\ \gcd(a,b) \end{eqnarray}$$

Then the above proof translates as below, $\ $ with $\,\ m(x,y) := {\rm min}(x,y)$

$c \le a,b \!\iff\!c\!+\!x \le a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x\!$ $\!\iff\! c\!+\!x \le m(a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x)\!$ $\!\iff\!\! c \le m(a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x)\!-\!x$

---

**Or** in any UFD we can induct on the number $\,k\,$ of prime factors of $\,x.\,$ If $\,k=0\,$ then $\,x\,$ is a unit thus $\,(ax,bx)=(a,b)x\,$ is clear. Else $\,x = yp\,$ for $\,p\,$ prime so by $\,\color{#c00}{I =\rm induction}$

$\begin{align}
{\rm if}\,\ p\nmid d\,\ &{\rm then}\,\ d\mid ayp,byp \iff\,\  d\mid ay,by \color{#c00}{\overset{ I\!\!\!}\iff}\ d\mid (a,b)y \iff d\mid (a,b)yp\\
{\rm if}\,\ p\mid d\,\ &{\rm then}\,\ d\mid ayp,byp \iff \frac{d}p\mid ay,by \color{#c00}{\overset{ I\!\!\!}\iff} \frac{d}p\mid (a,b)y \iff d\mid (a,b)yp\end{align}$

---

**Theorem** $\ \ $ If $\ a,b,x\ $ are positive naturals then $\ (ax,bx) = (a,b)x $

**Proof** $\ $ We induct on $\color{#0a0}{{\rm size}:= a\!+b}.\,$ If $\,a=b\,$ then it is true since both sides $= ax.\,$ Else $\,a\neq b;\,$ wlog, by symmetry, $\,a > b\,$ so $\,(ax,bx) = (ax\!-\!bx,bx) = \color{}{((a\!-\!b)x,bx)}\,$ with smaller $\rm\color{#0a0}{size}$ $\,(a\!-\!b) + b = a < \color{#0a0}{a\!+b},\,$ therefore $\,((a\!-\!b)x,bx)\!\underset{\rm induct}=\! (a\!-\!b,b)x = (a,b)x$.

---

For completeness below we present a proof of the **LCM Distributive Law** with notation $\,[x,y] := {\rm lcm}(x,y),\,$  using the [LCM universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) and basic divisibility properties.

**Theorem** $\ \ [ax,bx] \approx [a,b]x $

**Proof** $\ \ \smash{[ax,bx]\mid c\!\!\overset{\rm def\!\!\!}\iff ax,bx\mid c\iff a,b\mid c/x\!\!\overset{\rm def\!\!\!}\iff [a,b]\mid c/x\iff [a,b]x\mid c}$

Therefore $\rm\, [ax,bx] \approx [a,b]x\,$ are associate (divide each other) by above. In particular, they are equal if we are in $\Bbb Z$ and we [normalize lcms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242) to be positive. Similarly, more generally we have

**Theorem'** $\,\  [a,b]\,$ exists $\!\iff\! (ac,bc)$ exists for all $\,c\in D,\,$ for any $\,a,b,c\,$ in a domain $D$

**Proof** $\ \ (\Rightarrow)\,\ \ d\mid ac,bc \!\iff\! a,b\mid abc/d \!\iff\! [a,b]\mid abc/d \!\iff\! d\mid abc/[a,b]$

$(\Leftarrow)\,\ \ a,b\mid c\iff ab\mid ac,bc\iff ab\mid (ac,bc)\iff  abc/(ac,bc)\mid c$

$$\begin{align} {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \ \  [a,b]\ {\rm exists}\  &\Rightarrow (ac,bc) \approx abc/[a,b]\\[.3em]  
\forall c\!: (ac,bc)\ {\rm exists}\ &\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \, [a,b] \approx abc/(ac,bc) \approx ab/(a,b)\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3055362/242) and its links for methods exploiting innate duality between gcd & lcm.

Comment: In your first theorem, division by $x$ is not always possible since $D$ is merely an integral domain, not necessary a field. In addition, I fail to understand precisely what you mean. Greatest common divisors are not unique, so what do you mean by equality of $(a,b)$ and $(ax,bx)/x$?

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 The first proof cancels $\,x\neq 0\,$ which is valid since we presume the ring is a domain. Greatest common divisors are unique up to associates (unit multiples). To be rigorous we should write that the gcds are associate, but is a common abuse of language to use "equal" vs. "associate" (i.e. to implicitly work in the quotient monoid modulo the unit group).

Answer (score 11):

It's simpler, you don't need any identity, factorization, almost nothing apart from the fact the $\gcd$'s exist.

Let $c=\gcd(a,b)$ and $d=\gcd(ma,mb)$, then
$$c\mid a, b\Longrightarrow mc\mid ma, mb\Longrightarrow mc\mid d$$ so $d=mcx$, then $$mcx\mid ma, mb\Longrightarrow cx\mid a,b\Longrightarrow cx\mid c\Longrightarrow x\mid1$$

therefore $\gcd(ma, mb)=|m|\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: This is essentially the second proof in my answer, except that I exploit the universal gcd property to do *both* directions simultaneously, making the proof more succinct - a one liner.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Well I'm not sure OP knows what universal property is (well I only know it's some abstract nonsense from category theory), so I really want to avoid that.

Comment: The universal property of the gcd is simply $\ c\mid a,b\iff c\mid \gcd(a,b),\,$ analogous to $\,c\le a,b\iff c\le \min(a,b).\,$ No knowledge of category theory is needed to grok that. You use that implicitly above, but not as efficiently as can be done, since you do both directions *separately*.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Oh I see, it's quite nice, but I wanted to avoid division (I know I'm in an integral domain too, but it looks like fractions).

Comment: One can restructure to use cancellation vs. division if one prefers. Unfortunately these nice universal proofs are not as well known as they deserve to be, so I try to emphasize them whenever I get the chance.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply: Let $x=gcd(a,b).$ Then $a=xk$ and $b=xl$ for some coprime $k, l$ by definition of GCD.

Then $ma=mxk$ and $mb=mxl$.

Therefore, $gcd(ma,mb)=mx=mgcd(a,b)$ [because $gcd(k,l)=1$, so the greatest divisor of both $ma$, $mb$ must then be $mx$]. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Let $x = GCD(a,b)$: you have $$ a=a_1\cdot x, b=b_1\cdot x$$ where $GCD(a_1,b_1) = 1$.
Now $$GCD(ma,mb) = GCD(ma_1\cdot x,mb_1\cdot x) = mx$$ since $GCD(a_1,b_1) = 1$, so $$GCD(ma,mb) = m\cdot GCD(a,b)$$

Comment: Far too many details are omitted to judge if this is correct.

Comment: it was a kind of hint..