# In a commutative unital ring, can we find invertible codivisors for mutual divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's say we have a commutative ring $R$ with a unit and elements $a,b \in R$ which divide each other, e.g. $a | b$ and $b|a$. The question is now:

> Does there exist an invertible element $\epsilon \in R^\times$ with $a \epsilon = b$ or are there counterexamples e.g. rings and elements as above, for which you can't find such an $\epsilon$?

This question arose from an exercise I gave to my students for commutative rings without unit (where there are plenty counterexamples, e.g. $R=\mathbb Z \times 2\mathbb Z$). Since we couldn't find counterexamples or a proof for unital rings I am asking here the question.

**Stuff we already tried/figured out:**

- It is quite clear, that in a counterexample $a$ and $b$ are zerodivisors.
- It is useless to consider cross-products of rings, since you can solve the problem pointwise.
- $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ are no counterexamples.

Comment: At the very least, you can find such a $\epsilon$ if $R$ is a field.

Comment: The notion of associate, irreducible etc bifurcate in rings that are not domains, e.g. see the paper of Anderson I [linked here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/863228/242)  and [here 2009](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6895266). They mention various types of counterexamples that are well-known.

Comment: @BillDubuque We defined associate as what you called strong associate. Since I was seeing both notations around (personally I am more used to your notation), I figured it would be better to describe the relations directly instead of using notation which might differ.

Comment: That's D.D. Anderson's terminology, not mine. His papers are the first place to start when learning these topics (as I [often mentioned](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=1844267&messageID=6465378) on sci.math).

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah wonderful, I saw the mistake we did in the continuous functions. We tried something similar as the counterexample in the ande-paper but messed up at a point and got poles... Thank you very much, you helped a lot.

Comment: Iiirc that example is often attributed to Kaplansky but it is actually much older (but, alas, I cannot recall the source off the top of my head).

Comment: If the paper/example answers your question(s) then it makes sense to close your question as a dupe, e.g. of [this prior question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14270/242) If not then please make your question more specific