# Understanding $(x)=(y)$ in rings that aren't domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. I would like to get a better understanding of the equivalence relation on $R$ $$x\sim y\iff(x)=(y)\iff\exists u,v\in R,~x=uy~\text{ and }~y=vx$$
where $(x)$ is the principal ideal generated by $x$. Let us also write $$x\approx y\iff \exists u\in R^\times,~x=uy$$
Clearly $x\approx y\implies x\sim y$ holds in any ring.

> **Question 1.** Is there a nice description of $\sim$ equivalence classes as unions of $\approx$ equivalence classes ?

When $R$ is a domain these two equivalence relations are identical. But some non domains also satisfy this property, for instance all rings $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ have this property, too. Below we prove moregenerally that rings of the form $R/\mathfrak{a}$ for $R$ PID have this property. This raises the question:

> **Question 2.** Can one characterize the rings $R$ in which the relations $\sim$ and $\approx$ are identical?

One can make some simple observations, for instance $\sim$ equivalence classes agree with $\approx$ equivalence classes when $x$ is $0$, a unit or irreducible. If $x$ is cancellable in the sense that $xu=0\implies u=0$ then the equivalence classes agree, too. If $x\sim y$ and $x$ is nilpotent, then $y$ is nilpotent and $x$ and $y$ have the same nilpotency index, but I'm not sure they are necessarily $\approx$-equivalent.

> **Question 3.** For what types of elements of $R$ do the $\sim$ and $\approx$ equivalence classes agree ?

When $R$ is a domain one has that $x$ is irreducible if and only if $(x)$ is maximal in the set of proper principal ideals of $R$. In a general ring "irreducible implies maximal" holds.

> **Question 4.** What can be said about $x$ if $(x)$ is maximal in the set of principal ideals $<(1)$ ?

Finally, in order to build intuition, I would like to see some examples of non domains where the relations $\approx$ and $\sim$ agree and examples where they disagree.

> **Question 5.** What are some good examples of non domains where the relations $\approx$ and $\sim$ agree? Where they disagree?

---

### Generalizing the example $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ of rings where $\approx~=~\sim$

The fact that the $\sim$ and $\approx$ define the same equivalence relation in the rings $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ can be generalized:

> **Lemma.** Let $R$ be a PID and $\mathfrak{a}<(1)$ a proper ideal of $R$. Then $\sim$ and $\approx$ are identical in the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak{a}$.

I'm sure there is a more straightforward proof of this, but here goes.

**Proof.** Since $R$ is a domain there is nothing to prove for $\mathfrak{a}=(0)$. Suppose $(0)<\mathfrak{a}<(1)$ and let $x$ be a generator: $\mathfrak{a}=(x)$. Since PIDs are UFDs we can factor $x$ as a product of irreducibles $x=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{m_i}$, and so $\mathfrak{a}=(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\big(p_i^{m_i}\big)$. Since irreducibles are primes in UFDs and nonzero prime ideals are maximal in PIDs, the nonzero prime ideals $(p_i)=\sqrt{\big(p_i^{m_i}\big)}$ are maximal, pairwise distinct and therefore pairwise coprime. It follows that the ideals $(p_i^{m_i})$ are pairwise coprime. The chinese remainder theorem yields $$R/\mathfrak{a}\simeq\prod_{i=1}^nR/\big(p_i^{m_i}\big)$$
Now for any family of rings $(R_i)_{i\in I}$ we have $$\Big(\prod_{i\in I}R_i\Big)^\times=\prod_{i\in I}R_i^\times$$ and for any rings $R_1,\dots,R_n$ the ideals of the product ring are products of ideals:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\displaystyle
\left\{
\text{ideals of }
\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n R_i
\right\}
&=&
\displaystyle
\left\{
\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{a}_i
\text{ for ideals }\mathfrak{a}_i\subset R_i
\right\}
\\
\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-90deg)}{\subseteq}
&&
\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-90deg)}{\subseteq}
\\
\displaystyle
\left\{
\text{principal ideals of }
\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n R_i
\right\}
&=&
\displaystyle
\left\{
\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{a}_i
\text{ for principal ideals }\mathfrak{a}_i\subset R_i
\right\}
\end{array}$$
These two elementary propositions show that it is enough to prove that $\sim$ and $\approx$ are equal for quotient rings of the form $R/(p^n)$ for primes $p$ and positive $n$.

Thus, let $p$ be a prime of $R$ and $n\geq 1$ a positive integer. The ring $R/(p^n)$ is local and artinian (because noetherian and zero dimensional) and all its ideals are principal. The proof of **Theorem 8.5** in Atiyah-MacDonald shows that all its only ideals are the $(0)<\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}<\cdots<\mathfrak{m}<(1)$ for $k=0,\dots,n$ where $\mathfrak{m}=(p)/(p^n)$. Now suppose $(x)=(y)$. Then for some $k$, $(x)=\mathfrak{m}^k$ and so there exists $u$ with $x=up^k$. Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only prime ideal in $R/(p^n)$ we have $\sqrt{(0)}=\mathfrak{m}$ and $R/(p^n)=\Big(R/(p^n)\Big)^\times\sqcup \mathfrak{m}$. Therefore, if $u$ were noninvertible it would belong to $\mathfrak{m}$ and so $x\in(p^{k+1})$ whence $(x)\subseteq\mathfrak{m}^{k+1}<\mathfrak{m}^k$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $u$ is invertible. Similarly there exists $v$ invertible with $y=vp^k$ and so $x$ and $y$ are associates.

---

The paper referenced by @HansLundmark actually contains the preceding and generalizes it: $\sim$ and $\approx$ agree for all quasilocal rings, i.e. rings with only finitely many maximal ideals:

[image]

Since the maximal ideals of $R/\mathfrak{a}$ are precisely the $(p_i)/\mathfrak{a}$, $i=1,\dots,n$, quotients of PIDs are quasilocal and thus have the property that $\sim$ and $\approx$ are identical.

Comment: Some thoughts that are far from an answer: The equivalence class of $x$ with respect to $\sim$ consists of the elements of the form $rx$ such that $(1-rs)x = 0$ for some $s \in R$. The equivalence class of $x$ with respect to $\approx$, on the other hand, consists of the elements of the form $ux$ with $u \in R^\times$. Of course, setting $r = u, s = u^{-1}$ yields the already mentioned implication $x \approx y \Rightarrow x \sim y$. Both equivalence classes will coincide if whenever we have $rx$ such that $(1-rs)x = 0$ there exists $u \in R^\times$ for which $rx = ux$, i.e. $(1-ru)x = 0$.

Comment: (cont.) A sufficient condition would be to have $1-d$ non-reducible for all zero divisors $d$.
P.S.: I find this a very interesting question, where did this condition come up?

Comment: @guidoar The question stems from my discomfort of imposing domain conditions all the time ^^ I ask because I want clarity in my mind. Basically these questions cristalized when trying to answer the question: are irreducibles useful if the ring isn't a domain?

Comment: Ah, okay :) I find the problem interesting in of itself, I was asking mainly to have some examples at hand in which the notions do not coincide and see what's going on.

Comment: @guidoar that's an excellent point and I forgot to include a request for examples. Once I am home I will edit the question because I too would like good examples of this phenomenon.

Comment: Maybe of interest: D. D. Anderson & Silvia Valdes-Leon, “Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero Divisors”, Rocky Mountain J. Math. 26:2, 1996, 439-480, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072068.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you for that reference. They actually use the same notation as I did in my question for what associates ($a\sim b\iff (a)=(b)$) and strong associates ($a\approx b\iff \exists u\in U(R),~ a=ub$).

Comment: See the papers I cite in [thjis old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863228/242)

Comment: I haven't read all this carefully, but when I pondered this question independently some years ago, I came up with the ring $\Bbb Z[u,v,w]/(w(1-uv))$ in which non-associates generate the same ideal. I'm sure you've thought of this before, too.

Comment: @TedShifrin No I haven't, but it's very close to an example found in WHEN ARE ASSOCIATES UNIT MULTIPLES? by D.D. ANDERSON, M. AXTELL, S.J. FORMAN and JOE STICKLES BillDubuque links to (they take coefficients in a field rather than in the integers).

Comment: Yeah, I originally did this with field coefficients and then put the $\Bbb Z$ to make it a bit more universal :)