# $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)\,$ [Associative Law for GCD, LCM]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Prove $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$ for $0\ne a,b,c\in \Bbb{Z}$. I tried solving it with sets but I sense there are some details I am missing. I would truly appreciate your reference.

Answer (score 18):

**Hint** $ $ By $\,\color{#c00}{\rm U}= $ gcd Universal Property (see below) we have

$$d\mid(a,b,c)\!\!\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm\ U}\iff} d\mid a,b,c\!\!\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm\ U}\iff} d\,\mid (a,b),c\!\!\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm\ U}\iff} d\mid ((a,b),c)\qquad$$

So $\,(a,b,c)\,$ & $\,((a,b),c)\,$ divide each other (let $\,d\,$ equal each above) so they're equal, being $> 0$.

This is the **associative property** of the GCD.  In the same way, by induction, we can erase (or normalize) brackets in $n$-argument gcds,  showing general associativity of the gcd, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835226/242)

**Remark** $\ $ For completeness, below is a proof of $\,\color{#c00}{\rm U}= $ gcd Universal Property.

**Lemma** $\ \ d\mid a_1,\ldots,a_n\!\overset{\rm\color{#c00}U\!\!}\iff d\mid (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\ \ \ $ [[GCD Universal Property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242)

${\bf Proof}\quad\ d\mid a_1,\ldots,a_n\Rightarrow\, d\mid (a_1,\ldots,a_n) = j_1 a_1\!+\ldots+j_n a_n\,$ for some $\, j_i\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by [Bezout.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242)

$\qquad\qquad\, d\mid (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid a_1,\ldots,a_n\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a_1,\ldots,a_n\,$ by transitivity of $ $ "divides",

The second divisibility in the prior line is due to the gcd being a *common* divisor of its arguments.

**Remark** $ $ Dually, as above, associativity of LCM is immediate from the universal property of LCM

**Lemma** $\ \ a_1,\ldots,a_n\mid m\iff {\rm lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid m\ \ \ $ [[LCM Universal Property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242)

These universal properties are the *definitions* of GCD & LCM in more general rings  - where the Bezout identity need not hold true,  e.g. in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ where the gcds $\,(x,2) = 1 = (x,y)\,$ cannot be written as linear combinations. Follow the links for further details.

**Application to computation (Bezout)**  $ $ We can exploit gcd associativity to reduce many-argument (extended) gcd computations to compositions of two-argument (extended) gcds, e.g.

$$(a,b,c) = ((a,b),c) = i(a,b)+jc = i(ka\!+\!\ell b)+jc = ik\:\!a + i\ell\:\!b + j\:\!c\qquad$$

where $\,k,\ell\,$ are Bezout coefs for $\,e:=(a,b) = ka+\ell b,\,$ and $\,i,j\,$ for $(e,c) = ie+jc$

Algebraically the key idea is that integer linear combinations of $\,a,b,c\,$ are *closed under integer linear combinations* - which combined with gcd associativity allows us to decompose many-argument gcds in any way we please (as long as all arguments are included). This innate *linearity* is clarified when one studies ideals and modules.

Alternatively, we can directly apply the *forward* (extended) Euclidean algorithm, e.g, as [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338268/242) which generally will be more efficient for many-argument gcds.

Comment: How is it concluded (generally) that for evry $d|a,b \Rightarrow$ $d|\gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: @Meitar See the added Remark.

Comment: Oh... I wasn't taught Bezout theorem. I shall look for it.

Comment: @Meitar I added a link to a simple, conceptual proof.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque , what does the | symbol mean ?

Comment: @Elvin $\ a\mid b\ $ means $a$ divides $b,\,$ i.e. $\,an = b\,$ for some integer $\,n.\,$ This is widely used notation in number theory.

Comment: It is disturbing to me how 4 pages of meandering in my notebook can be replaced by 3 lines of clarity.

Answer (score 16):

The def of $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is $d|a$ and $d|b$ and if $f|a$ and $f|b$ then $f|d$.

Suppose $x=\gcd(a,b,c)$.  Then $x|a$ and $x|b$ and $x|c$ so $x|\gcd(a,b)$ and $x|c$, so $x|\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$.  Conversely if $x=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$ then $x|\gcd(a,b)$ and $x|c$.  So $x|a$ and $x|b$ and $x|c$, so $x|\gcd(a,b,c)$.  Thus $\gcd(a,b,c) | \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$ and $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)| \gcd(a,b,c)$.  Therefore $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c) = \gcd(a,b,c)$

Comment: In the definition I was given, nothing is said about every divisor dividing the gcd. How is it shown?

Comment: It doesn't need to be shown, it's part of the definition, so you can assume it once you know $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then automatically any other divisor of $a$ and $b$ must divide $d$.

Comment: Please post the definition you were given, so we can see how it differs from this one I gave.

Comment: "The greatest common divisor (gcd) of two or more integers, when at least one of them is not zero, is the largest positive integer that divides the numbers without a remainder."

Answer (score 0):

A different definition of gcd affords another proof.

For $p_i\in \mathbb P \land p_i\mid abc$, then $a=\prod p_i^{\alpha_i},\ b=\prod p_i^{\beta_i},\ c=\prod p_i^{\gamma_i} \Rightarrow  \gcd(a,b,c)=\prod p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i)}$

Note that in some cases, an exponent $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i$ will be $0$ when a particular $p_i$ is not a factor of one or another of $a,b,c$, but since $p_i\mid abc$, at least one of $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i$ will be greater than $0$

Similarly, $\gcd(a,b)=\prod p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i)}$

Hence, $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)=\prod p_i^{\min({\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i)},\gamma_i)}=\prod p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i)}=\gcd(a,b,c)$ QED

Answer (score 0):

Since the minimum over a set is no greater than the minimum over a subset,
$$
\begin{align}
\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)
&={\min_{u,v}}^+\!\left({\min_{x,y}}^+(ax+by)u+cv\right)\\
&\ge{\min_{x,y,z}}^+(ax+by+cz)\\
&=\gcd(a,b,c)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
$\gcd(a,b)\mid a,b$ and so $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)\mid a,b,c$. Thus, by the maximality of the gcd,
$$
\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)\le\gcd(a,b,c)\tag2
$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)=\gcd(a,b,c)\tag3
$$

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to see this is to realize that $\mbox{min}(x,y,z)=\mbox{min}(\mbox{min}(x,y),z)$. for integers $x,y,z$.

How do we use this?  Fix a $p$ and determine its exponent on each side. For this, it suffices to imagine that $a,b,c$ are powers of a fixed prime $p$.  Then if $a=p^x,b=p^y,c=p^z$, we have $$\mbox{gcd}(a,b,c)=p^{\mbox{min}(x,y,z)}=p^{\mbox{min}(\mbox{min}(x,y),z)}=\mbox{gcd}(p^{\mbox{min}(x,y)},p^z)=\mbox{gcd}(\mbox{gcd}(a,b),c).$$

This is true for each $p$, so the two sides must be equal.

Answer (score -1):

**Proof:** Let $d=gcd(a,b,c)$ for positive integers $a$,$b$, and $c$. Then $d\mid a$, $d\mid b$, and $d\mid c$. Hence, $d\mid gcd(a,b)$ and $d\mid c$ and so $d\mid gcd(gcd(a,b),c)$. Thus, $d\mid f$ where $f=gcd(e,c)$ and $e=gcd(a,b)$. Since $f=gcd(e,c)$, then $f\mid e$ and $f\mid c$. Hence, $f\mid a$, $f\mid b$, and $f\mid c$, so $f\mid gcd(a,b,c)$ which means $f\mid d$. Since $d\mid f$ and $f\mid d$, $d=f$.