# Is this possible to solve through algebra?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, congruences

$$150 \equiv 17 \mod x, \qquad
100 \equiv 5 \mod x $$

Solve the simultaneous equation?
Is this even a simultaneous equation?
How do I find the value of $x$ too?
I was doing a question and came up with these equations...I know the basics of modular arithmetic but don't really know too difficult ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $150-17=133$, we have
$$
150\equiv17\pmod{x}\implies x\mid133
$$
Furthermore, since $100-5=95$, we have
$$
100\equiv5\pmod{x}\implies x\mid95
$$
The possibilities for $x$ can be derived from the fact that $133=7\cdot19$ and $95=5\cdot19$.

Comment: So we have use common factor to find the value of x?

Comment: Well, we must have $x\mid19$. This leaves more than one possibility for $x$.

Comment: I see...Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b,c,d$ are specific numbers  and $x$ is unknown (all positive integers)
then the equation $a\equiv b\pmod x$ and $c\equiv d\pmod x$ by definition means $x$ is a common divisor of the two numbers $a-b$ and $c-d$.

The solution need not be unique.  So solving them is the same as finding the set of all common divisors. This is same as finding $g=\gcd(a-b,c-d)$ and then  listing all divisors of $g$.

Comment: So,can the solution be 1?since it is not unique?

Comment: It should be called the trivial solution, it is always there. as the statement $1$ divides any any positive integer though correct and important, is not a profound statement. Unique solution means it has to be $1$.

Comment: I see.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The given equations imply $150-17=7\cdot19$ and $100-5=5\cdot19$ to be multiples of $x$. The $\gcd$ is $19$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition your system is equivalent to $\ x\mid 133,\ x\mid 95,\,\ $ i.e. $\,\ x\mid 133,195$.

The [universal property of the gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) tells us how to combine this pair of divisibility statements into an *equivalent* single divisibility statement, namely

$$ x\mid a,b \iff x\mid \gcd(a,b)$$

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is down voted. Strange.