# Prove that $\operatorname {gcd}(\operatorname {gcd}(m,n), p) = \operatorname {gcd}(m,\operatorname {gcd}(n, p))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that
$$\operatorname {gcd}(\operatorname {gcd}(m,n), p) = \operatorname {gcd}(m,\operatorname {gcd}(n, p))$$

---

How to begin ?

Comment: Probably with the definition, or some lemmas that you've encountered in your course.

Comment: Show that each is equal to $gcd(m,n,p)$ by arguing $\le$ and then $\ge$.

Comment: But for stating that $
\operatorname {gcd}(m,n,p)$ is defined we first need to prove the statement given in the question.

Comment: @arutoregni may you check on my answer, if you find it answers your question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to prove it is the following. Let $d_1=\operatorname {gcd}(\operatorname {gcd}(m,n), p)$ and $d_2=\operatorname {gcd}(m, \operatorname {gcd}(n,p))$. Consider $d_1$. Then we have: $d_1$ divides both $\operatorname {gcd}(m,n)$ and $p$, hence $d_1$ divides $m, n$. Further, $d_1$ divides $p$, then $d_1$ divides $\operatorname {gcd}(n, p)$. It follows that $d_1$ divides $(m, \operatorname {gcd}(n,p))$, so it divides $d_2=\operatorname {gcd}(m, \operatorname {gcd}(n,p))$. In particular, $d_1$ divides $d_2$. Now exchange the roles of $d_1, d_2$ and conclude that $d_2$ divides $d_1$, which implies $d_1=d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of a much more general result, and is best proved at a higher level of generality.

> **Proposition.** Let $P$ denote a poset. Let $a,b$ and $c$ denote elements of $P$, such every subset of $\{a,b,c\}$ has a join. Then: $$(a \vee b) \vee c = a \vee (b \vee c).$$

We then get the desired result in the special case where $P$ is the poset $(\mathbb{N},\mid^{op})$, in which case $\vee$ is just the $\mathrm{gcd}$. (If you don't know what the hell I'm talking about, I suggest getting yourself a good book on the matter. Order theory is both beautiful and useful. [Davey and Priestley's book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/introduction-lattices-and-order-2nd-edition) is a pretty good place to start.)

*Proof.*

Consider $k \in P$. Then the following are equivalent:

- $k \geq (a \vee b) \vee c$
- $k \geq (a \vee b)$ and $k \geq c$
- $k \geq a$ and $k \geq b$ and $k \geq c$
- $k \geq a$ and $k \geq (b \vee c)$
- $k \geq a \vee (b \vee c)$

Hence: $$\forall k \in P(k \geq (a \vee b) \vee c \iff k \geq a \vee (b \vee c))$$

Hence: $$(a \vee b) \vee c = a \vee (b \vee c)$$

Like every proof in order theory, the above is based on the "Yoneda lemma for posets":

> **Proposition.** Let $P$ denote a partially ordered set. Let $a$ and $b$ denote elements of $P$. Then: $$a \geq b \iff \forall k \in P(k \geq a \implies  k \geq b)$$

This implies

> **Corollary.** Let $P$ denote a partially ordered set. Let $a$ and $b$ denote elements of $P$. Then: $$a = b \iff \forall k \in P(k \geq a \iff  k \geq b)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ d\mid (m,n),p \iff d\mid m,n,p\iff d\mid m,(n,p)\ $ so $\,(m,n),p\,$ and $\,m,(n,p)\,$ have the same set $\,S\,$ of *common* divisors, hence the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S)$.

Above we employed twice the gcd [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) $\, d\mid (a,b)\iff d\mid a,b$.