# Prove that if $n_1$ and $n_2$ divide $n$ and $\gcd(n_1,n_2) = 1$, then $n_1 n_2$ divides $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $n_1$ and $n_2$ divide $n$ and $\gcd(n_1,n_2) = 1$, then $n_1 n_2$ divides $n$.

I start by letting $n = n_1 k$ and $n = n_2 h$, and I know I'm trying to show that $n = q n_1 n_2$ but I can't figure a way to show this.

Comment: Can you take prime decompositions?

Comment: Hint try and use the fact that since $gcd(n_1,n_2) =1$ there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1= an_1 + bn_2$

Comment: @Nex : Note the use of \gcd in MathJax, as in my edit to the question. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be such that $1=xn_1+yn_2$. Multiplying both sides by $n$ and using your two decompositions of $n$ gives
$$
n=nxn_1+nyn_2=hn_2xn_1+kn_1yn_2\\=(hx+ky)n_1n_2
$$

Answer (score 1):

$ a,b\mid n\iff ab\mid an,bn\iff ab\mid (an,bn)\!=\! \color{#c00}{(a,b)}n\,\ [= n\ \ {\rm if}\ \  \color{#c00}{(a,b)= 1}]$

**Corollary** $\,\  a,b\mid n \iff \dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}\mid\, n,\ $ thus $\,\ {\rm lcm}(a,b) = \dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}$

Comment: What's the difference between $ab \text{ } | \text{ } an,bn$ and $ab \text{ } | \text{ } (an,bn)$?

Comment: @OliverG $\ (x,y) \,$ is standard notation for $\,\gcd(x,y).\, $ That equivalence is the universal property of the gcd [(see here)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242), usually taken as the definition of the gcd in more general rings (which may have no notion of magnitude).