# GCD: If $d\mid a, d\mid b$, and $d\mid c$, then $d|\mid \gcd(a,b,c)$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

How do I prove that If $d\mid a, d\mid b$, and $d\mid c$, then $d\mid \gcd(a,b,c)$ without using gcd(a,b,c)=gcd(gcd(a,b),c)?

I understand that the Common Divisor Divides GCD is only defined for two variables.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189424/prove-gcda-b-c-gcd-gcda-b-c), which proves both associativity and the sought universal property. The proof obviously extends n-ary gcds.

Comment: See also [$d\mid a,b \iff d\mid\gcd(a,b) \ $ \[GCD Universal Property\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242)

Comment: Re: your edit "without using...": the linked proof in the dupe doesn't use that (associativity) rather it uses Bezout. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377940/242) is a proof of Bezout for any number of arguments.

Comment: The GCD of $n>0$ integers is defined to be their greatest common divisor - same as when $n = 2$.

Comment: "I understand that the Common Divisor Divides GCD is only defined for two variables."  Why do you say that? "common divisor divides GCD" is not a *definition*.  It's a provable statement of fact.  And you can prove it for any number of terms the exact same way.  If $d< \gcd(a,b,c)$ is a common divisor $d\not \mid \gcd(a,b,c)$ then $\gcd(gcd(a,b,c), d)*\gcd(a,b,c)$ is a common divisor contradicting that $\gcd(a,b,c)$ is the greatest.  The number of terms with a common divisor have nothing relevant to do with it.

Comment: @fleablood Correct is: $\,g,d\mid a,b,c\iff [g,d]\mid a,b,c,\,$ and $\,[g,d]=gd/(g,d),\,$ not $\,(g,d)g,\,$ i.e. common divisors are closed under lcm (which *increases* for divisibly-incomparable args)