# Find the coefficients of gcd(a,b,c) as a linear combination?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given numbers $a,b,c\in\mathbb N$, say $k$ be the smallest positive linear combination of $\{a,b,c\}$. Now consider $a$, if:

$$
a=kq+r, 0\lt r\lt k,
$$

then there exists a smaller positive linear combination of $\{a,b,c\}$, a contradiction, so $r=0$. The idea for $b,c$ is the same, we get $k$ divides $a,b,c$. Let $d=\gcd(a,b,c)$, since $d$ divides $k$ and $k\le d$, $k=d$.

So $\gcd(a,b,c)$ can be defined to be the smallest positive linear combination of $\{a,b,c\}$, but how to find the coefficient of $a,b,c$ respectively?

Comment: Use $\gcd(a,b,c) = \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$ and the extended Euclidean algorithm twice.

Comment: i.e. exploit the fact that [gcd is **associative**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377940/242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From extended Euclidean algorithm, we can find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ such taht

$$gcd(a,b)=\alpha a + \beta b$$

$$gcd(a,b,c)=gcd(gcd(a,b), c)= \gamma c + \delta \gcd(a,b)$$

Hence

$$\gcd(a,b,c) = \alpha \delta a + \beta \delta b + \gamma c$$