# The relationship between GCD and LCM

Tags: number-theory

I am completing a problem in hackerrank that counts the number of integers that can be divided by all elements of a set $A$ and divide all elements of another set $B$.

I completed the problem using a ugly brute force method then found the following solution.

1. Find the LCM of $A$
2. Find the GCD of $B$
3. Find how many divisors $GCD(B)/LCM(A)$ has.

From going through a few examples I can see that it works. I am not sure WHY though.

Comment: it because there a property that say tha for 2 integers number $\text{lcm}(a,b)\text{gcd}(a,b)=ab$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [universal properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) of $\rm gcd$ and $\rm lcm$ we have

$\qquad\begin{align} a_1,\ldots,a_j\mid n &\iff  L:= {\rm lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_j)\mid n\\[.5em]
                     n\mid b_1,\ldots,b_k &\iff n\mid \gcd(b_1,\ldots,b_k) =: G \end{align}$

So both hold $\iff \ L\mid n\mid G\,\iff\, L\mid n,G \ $ & $\  n/L \mid G/L$

Therefore your method is correct: $ $ find all divisors $\,n/L\,$ of $\,G/L,\,$ then scale each by $L$ to get $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If all elements of $A$ divide a number $c$, that means there is an integer $n$ with $c = n\cdot\mathrm{LCM}(A)$. Similarly, if $c$ divides every element of $B$, then there is an integer $m$ with $mc = \mathrm{GCD}(B)$. Thus, for each number $c$ that has the aforementioned properties, there is a unique pair of integers $(m,n)$ such that $mn\cdot\mathrm{LCM}(A)= \mathrm{GCD}(B)$, or equivalently that $mn = \mathrm{GCD}(B)/\mathrm{LCM}(A)$. Clearly there is one such pair for each divisor of $\mathrm{GCD}(B)/\mathrm{LCM}(A)$.