# Show that there exists integers $w,z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)w+cz=e$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $\gcd(a,b,c)\mid e$ .
>   Show that there exists integers $w,z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)w+cz=e$

Assume that $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then $a=dp,b=dq$.

Also there exists integers $m,n$ such that $am+nb=d$.

How to find integers $w,z$ such that $dw+cz=e$?

Can someone please give some hint?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ [GCD is Associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) so $\ ((a,b),c) = (a,b,c)\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that (see [wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation))  the linear Diophantine equation $dw+cz=e$ has a solution $(w,z)$ if and only if $\gcd(d,c)$ divides $e$. But this is true because
$$\gcd(d,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)=\gcd(a,b,c).$$

Comment: I dont get it.can you elaborate?

Comment: What is your doubt?

Comment: Why is $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)=\gcd(a,b,c)$

Comment: This is a known property of $\gcd$. See the 11th one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties

Comment: Oh okay,thank you so much sir

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Can you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325185/665065