# Find all the integral solutions to the equation $323x+391y+437z=10473$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all the integral solutions to the equation $323x+391y+437z=10473$.

I know how to find integer solutions in two variables using Diophantine Equations.

But I am stuck here because it involves 3 variables.

Can I get a hint?

Comment: It might be helpful to factor each of the coefficients in this one. They set up a nice set of relations that you can then solve.

Comment: From your original question is sounds like you are completely stuck. Please show all the work you have, and what techniques/what you want explained in the answers so that others can better answer your question.

Comment: Your question just asks for a hint.  That's fine, but your comments on some of the answers below seem to suggest that you are not satisfied with hints and are looking for a full answer.  This is a little inconsiderate of those who have taken the trouble to try to respond to your question.  Please try to formulate questions so that they make clear exactly what you are looking for (and as Toby Mak says include your own thoughts / work).

Comment: I added a proof of the general formula cited in Robert's answer, and also added an answer using (Hermite) row reduction for comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242) that - by linearity -  the general solution of a  non-homogeneous linear equation is obtained by $\color{#0a0}{\text{adding}}$ any particular solution $\rm P$ to the general solution $\rm H$ of the associated homogeneous equation.  We can use this to reduce the solution of a trivariate linear Diophantine equation to the well-known bivariate case as below. Here I have followed the presentation that is implicit in the (unproved) [formula applied](http://mathafou.free.fr/exe_en/exedioph3.html) in Robert's answer, and also appended a complete proof of that (unproven) formula.

**Homogeneous solution:** $\ 323 x + 391 y = - 437 z\ $ is solved as below:

$\gcd(323,391) = 17\mid 437z\,\Rightarrow\, 17\mid z,\ $ so $\ z = 17 m\,$ for $\,m\in\Bbb Z$

Cancelling $\,17\,$ above yields: $\ \,19x\, +\, 23 y\, = -437m.\, $ Recursively solving this bivariate case:

$\ \ \ $ Particular solution: $\bmod 19\!:\ 4y\equiv 0\iff y\equiv 0,\ $ so $\ x = {\large \frac{-437m}{19}} = -23m$

$\ \ \ $ Homogeneous solution: $\ 19x+23y = 0\iff {\large \frac{y}x =\, \frac{\!\!-19}{23}}\!$  [$ \iff$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) $(x,y) = (23k,-19k)$

$\ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\text{Adding}}\rm\ P\!+\!H\!:$ $\ (x,y,z)\, =\, (23k,\, -19(m\!+\!k),\, 17m) = $ general homogeneous solution.

**Particular solution**  $\ (x,y,z) = (8,9,10)\ $ is obtained as follows:

$10473 = 437z + 17(\color{#c00}{19x\!+\!23y}) =: 437z + 17\,\color{#c00}T  $

$\!\bmod 17\!:\ z \equiv {\large \frac{10473 }{437}\equiv \frac{1}{12} \equiv \frac{18}2\frac{18}6}\equiv 9\cdot 3\equiv 10\ $ so $\ \color{#c00}T = {\large \frac{10473-437(10)}{17}} = \color{#c00}{359}$

$\color{#c00}{19x\!+\!23y = 359}\ $ $\Rightarrow \bmod 19\!:\ \begin{align}4y&\equiv -2\\  2y&\equiv -1\equiv 18\end{align}\!\!\iff y\equiv 9\ $ so $\,x = {\large \frac{359-23(9)}{19}} = 8$

$\color{#0a0}{\text{Adding}}\rm\ P\!+\!H\!:$ $\,\  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{(x,y,z) = (8\!+\!23k,\, 9\!-\!19(m\!+\!k),\, 10\!+\!17m)}\:$ is a general solution.

---

Below is a complete proof of the cited formula - proved exactly as above.

**Theorem** $ $ Let $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb Z\,$ with gcd $\,(a,b,c) = 1,\,$ let gcd  $\, (a,b) =: g,\,$ and $\,a' = a/g,\ b' = b/g.$

Let $\ \ z_0,\, t_0\in\Bbb Z\,\ $ be any solution of $\, \ c\,z\:\! +\ g\,t\, =\, d$
and $\  \color{#90f}{u_0,v_0}\in\Bbb Z\ $ be any solution of $\ \, a'u + b'v\, =\, c$
and $\  x_0, y_0\in\Bbb Z\ $ be any solution of $\ \ a'x + b'y =\:\! t_0$.

Then $\,ax + by + cz = d\,$  has the general solution
$\,\ \begin{align} 
 x &= x_0 + b'k - u_0 m\\
 y &= y_0 - a'k - v_0 m\\
 z &= z_0 + gm\end{align}\,\ $  for any $\,k,m\in\Bbb Z$

**Proof:** $ $ **Homogeneous solution:** $\ a x + b y = -c z\ $ is solved as below:

$(a,b)\!=\! g\mid cz\overset{(g,\,c)=1}\Rightarrow\! g\mid z,\ $ so $\ z = g m,\,m\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by $(g,c)\! =\! (a,b,c)\!=\!1\,$ & $ $ Euclid's Lemma.

Cancel $\,g\,$ in $\,ax+by = -cz\,$ $\Rightarrow \,a'x\, +\,b' y\, = -cm.\, $ Recursively solving this bivariate case:

$\ \ \ $ Particular solution: $\ (x,y) = (-u_0m,-v_0m)\ $ by $\,\color{#90f}{u_0,v_0}\,$ hypothesis scaled by $\,-m$.

$\ \ \ $ Homogeneous solution: $\ a'x+b'y = 0\iff {\large \frac{y}x =\, \frac{\!\!-a'}{b'}}\!$  [$ \iff$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) $(x,y) = (b'k,-a'k)$

$\ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\text{Adding}}\rm\ P\!+\!H\!:$ $\ (x,y,z)\, =\, (b'k\!-\!u_0m,\, -a'k\!-\!v_0m,\, gm) = $ general homogeneous solution.

**Particular solution**  $\,\ (x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)\ $ is obtained as follows:

$d = cz + g(\color{#c00}{a'x\!+\!b'y}) =: cz + g\,\color{#c00}t\  $ has solution $\,(z,\color{#c00}t) = (z_0,\color{#c00}{t_0})\,$ by hypothesis.

and also: $\, \ \ \ \color{#c00}{a'x\!+\!b'y = t_0}\,\ $ has $ $ as $ $ a $ $ solution: $\ \,  (x,y) = (x_0,y_0)\,$ by hypothesis.

Therefore $\,(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)\,$ is a particular solution.

$\color{#0a0}{\text{Adding}}\,$ the Particular and Homogeneous solutions yields the claimed general solution.

**Remark** $ $ If $\, e := (a,b,c) > 1\,$ then $\,e\mid d\,$  so cancelling $e$ in the equation reduces to the above case.

Comment: Thank you sir for taking the time to explain

Comment: @Bill Dubuque can you please explain in line 9 of proof of theorem what do you mean by " recursively solving the bivariate case" ?

Comment: @InvisibleMan That remark is meant to emphasize that the solution method can be viewed as a recursive algorithm that reduces the number of variables (above from $3$ to $2$ variables), cf. the first paragraph of the answer. The same method works for any number of variables.

Comment: @BillDubuque can you please tell how you got particular solution as $ -u_0 m $and $ -v_0 m$ ?

Comment: @BillDubuque can you please reply to above mentioned question?

Comment: @Inv The inductive step reduces to equations with fewer variables (here $2$ variables). One of these reduced equations is $\, a'u + b' v = c.\ $ We denote a particular solution of that by $\,\color{#90f}{u_0,v_0},\,$ so $\, a' u_0 + b' v_0 = c.\ $ To get a particular solution for RHS $=(-m)c$ vs. $c$ we scale the equation by $\,-m,\,$ which, by linearity, also scales our particular solution by $\,-m,\,$ i.e. $\, a'(-u_0m) + b'(-v_0m) = -cm\,$ has particular solution $\,(x,y) = (-u_0m,-v_0m) = -m(u_0,v_0).\ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Reducing $323x+391y+437z=10473\ $ modulo $\,17\,$ yields  $\,12z\equiv1\pmod{\!17}$.  Similar constraints can be found on $x$ by reducing $\!\bmod 23\,$ and $y$ by reducing $\!\bmod 19$.

Comment: and all of them need to be odd based on parity, or exactly 1 of them.

Comment: @BillDubuque Just notified me about your answer. You did indeed supply the OP with a hint (+1). I am marking my answer as community wiki now,...

Answer (score 2):

Since $\gcd(323,391,437)=1$ divide $10473$ we are supposed to find infinite solutions.

**Hint**.  First find a solution $u_0$, $v_0$ of $$19u + 23 v = 437$$ 
where $19=323/17$ and $23=391/17$ with $17=\gcd(323,391)$.
Then let $t_0$, $z_0$ be a solution of 
$$17t+ 437z=10473$$ 
and  $x_0$, $y_0$ be a solution of 
$$19x + 23y = t_0.$$ 
Then $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a particular solution of $323x+391y+437z=10473$, whereas the **general solution** is given by
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_0 - 23k - u_0j\\
y = y_0 + 19k - v_0j\\
z = z_0 + 17j \end{cases}$$
with $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then compare your result given by [Script](http://mathafou.free.fr/exe_en/exedioph3.html).

P.S. Finally, I got the general solution:
$$\begin{cases}
x = 8 - 23k -23j\\
y = 9 + 19k\\
z = 10 + 17j \end{cases}\tag{*}$$
with $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Verification that (*) are ALL the solutions of the given linear Diophantine equation**. It is easy to check that the particular solution $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(8,9,10)$ works. Moreover, the related homogeneous equation is
$$323(x-x_0)+391(y-y_0)+437(z-z_0)\\=17\cdot 19 (x-x_0)+17\cdot 23(y-y_0)+19\cdot 23 (z-z_0)=0$$
and it follows that  $z-z_0$ is a multiple of $17$, i.e. $z = z_0 + 17j$,  $y-y_0$ is a multiple of $19$, i.e. $y = y_0 + 19k$, and therefore
$$x=x_0-\frac{391(y-y_0)+437(z-z_0)}{323}=x_0-\frac{(17\cdot 19)\cdot 23 k+(19\cdot 23) \cdot 17j}{17\cdot 19}\\=x_0-23k-23j$$
and we are done.

Note that along the same lines, you may show that the method outlined above works in general.

Comment: I did that exactly

Comment: on solving the first equation i got (1885140+437t,-73311-437t)

Comment: But how to complete

Comment: i dont get it, can u help me to complete my solution

Comment: how to arrive to solution from this solution $(1885140+437t,-73311-437t)$

Comment: @Math_Freak I added a useful link to my answer.

Comment: no but i dont want to solve it using software,i want to know how to compute it,just tell me what to do after the hint without software

Comment: @Math_Freak See my directions.

Comment: It would be helpful to clearly explain *why* that is the *general* solution (no one has done this yet, and we may be missing that reasoning on the site). @Math_Freak I recommend that you don't accept any answer that does not do so - since this is crucial in order to properly answer your question, i.e. find *all* solutions.

Comment: Looking closer it seems you are simply applying the formula given *without proof* on the [web page](http://mathafou.free.fr/exe_en/exedioph3.html) that you linked.But why should anyone have faith in the correctness of a formula on some random web page?

Comment: @BillDubuque; I dont know why OP is just following the instructions on the webpage without even answering my question of why should we do it

Comment: @Math_Freak I verified that the given instructions provide ALL the solutions of your Diophantine equation. Along the same lines, you may show that the method works in general.

Comment: @Math_Freak I posted a  complete *proof* in an answer, following closely the  method hinted by the formula linked by Robert (so that you can prove this general  formula in exactly the same way I do your case).

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand that you don't like my answer...

Comment: Thank you for giving the method and now I have obtained the proof from another answer posted below too.

Comment: @Math_Freak You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm**

The Extended Euclidean Algorithm is usually applied to a pair of numbers, but by combining the results from the pairs $(391,323)$, $(437,391)$, and $(437,323)$, we can get a similar result for the triple $(437,391,323)$.

---

Applying the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) to $391$ and $323$
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&4&1&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-4&5&-19\\
0&1&-1&5&-6&23\\
391&323&68&51&17&0\\
\end{array}
$$
we get $\gcd(391,323)=17$ and
$$
\begin{align}
5\cdot391-6\cdot323&=17\tag{1a}\\
19\cdot391-23\cdot323&=0\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to $437$ and $391$
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&8&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-8&17\\
0&1&-1&9&-19\\
437&391&46&23&0\\
\end{array}
$$
we get $\gcd(437,391)=23$ and
$$
\begin{align}
9\cdot391-8\cdot437&=23\tag{2a}\\
19\cdot391-17\cdot437&=0\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to $437$ and $323$
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&2&1&5\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&3&-17\\
0&1&-1&3&-4&23\\
437&323&114&95&19&0\\
\end{array}
$$
we get $\gcd(437,323)=19$ and
$$
\begin{align}
3\cdot437-4\cdot323&=19\tag{3a}\\
17\cdot437-23\cdot323&=0\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Writing $\bf{1}$ as a Linear Combination of $\bf{323}$, $\bf{391}$, and $\bf{437}$**

Since $17$, $19$, and $23$ share no common factors, we can write $1$ as a linear combination of $323$, $391$, and $437$.

We start by applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to $23$ and $17$, the gcds in $\text{(2a)}$ and $\text{(1a)}$:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&2&1&5\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&3&-17\\
0&1&-1&3&-4&23\\
23&17&6&5&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
We get that $\gcd(23,17)=1$ and
$$
3\cdot23-4\cdot17=1\tag4
$$
Applying $\text{(1a)}$ and $\text{(2a)}$ to $(4)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=3\cdot\overbrace{23}^\text{(2a)}-4\cdot\overbrace{17}^\text{(1a)}\\
&=3(9\cdot391-8\cdot437)-4(5\cdot391-6\cdot323)\\
&=24\cdot323+7\cdot391-24\cdot437\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(5)$ shows how to write $1$ as a linear combination of $323$, $391$, and $437$. Using $\text{(3b)}$, $(5)$ can be reduced to
$$
1=1\cdot323+7\cdot391-7\cdot437\tag6
$$

---

**Writing $\bf{10473}$ as a Linear Combination of $\bf{323}$, $\bf{391}$, and $\bf{437}$**

We can simply multiply $(6)$ by $10473$ and reduce using $\text{(1b)}$ and $\text{(2b)}$:
$$
\begin{align}
10473
&=10473\cdot323+73311\cdot391-73311\cdot437\\
&+455\,(19\cdot391-23\cdot323)\tag{7a}\\
&=8\cdot323+81956\cdot391-73311\cdot437\\
&-4313\,(19\cdot391-17\cdot437)\tag{7b}\\
&=8\cdot323+9\cdot391+10\cdot437\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a)}$: reduce the coefficient of $323$ using $\text{(1b)}$
$\text{(7b)}$: reduce the coefficient of $391$ using $\text{(2b)}$
$\text{(7c)}$: a reduced linear combination

---

**The General Solution**

The difference of two solutions to $323x+391y+437z=10473$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation
$$
323x+391y+437z=0\tag8
$$
Consequences of $(8)$:
Since $\gcd(323,437)=23$, we have $23\mid x$, so WLOG let $x=23a$.
Since $\gcd(391,437)=19$, we have $19\mid y$, so WLOG let $y=19b$.
Since $\gcd(323,391)=17$, we have $17\mid z$.
Note that $323(23a)+391(19b)=437(17a+17b)$, so we need $z=-17a-17b$.

Therefore, the general solution to $(8)$ is
$$
323(23a)+391(19b)-437(17a+17b)=0\tag9
$$
Thus, combining $\text{(7c)}$ and $(9)$, the general solution to $323x+391y+437z=10473$ is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{10473=(8+23a)\,323+(9+19b)\,391+(10-17a-17b)\,437}\tag{10}
$$
Looking at $(10)$, it appears that $\text{(7c)}$ is the only solution with all positive coefficients.

Comment: It would be helpful to clearly explain *why* that is the *general* solution (no one has done this yet, and we may be missing that reasoning on the site).

Comment: I dont know why everyone is just doing some random calculation and saying that this is the required answer without even bothering to explain how to solve this problem

Comment: @BillDubuque: in [the answer cited above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), this is discussed in a couple of places. I will try to add something about it here.

Comment: @Math_Freak: have you read about the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or [the implementation cited above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021)? I am working on more explanation to add here, but the more you read about the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, the more these "random calculations" might make sense.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I tried to expand this answer to explain the role of the homogeneous solution, but it dragged the answer off point and confused the issue. I will expand another answer whose point is the inner workings of the algorithm and not its use.

Comment: @robjohn Alas, I still don't see any *proof* backing up the claim that the given solution is general. So little is written in the final paragraph that it is far from clear what is intended.

Comment: @BillDubuque: as I said, the proof for the completeness of answers belongs in the details of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, and I will expand on that in the proof of that theorem. Or are you saying that assuming the completeness of the two variable answer, it is not clear how this gives all solutions of the three variable answer?

Comment: @robjohn The latter. I think you should be more precise about how you obtain the general solution for the 3 variable case from the 2 variable case. Though *I* can figure out what you mean, I think this will be more difficult for someone first learning this. I will post an answer soon of you don't have time.

Comment: @robjohn Your edit clarifies your derivation of the general solution. It might be helpful for beginners if you say explicitly how you obtain $(9)$, esp. how the value for $z$ arises. I added a Remark in my answer which uses Hermite row reduction. This is related to your method, so there is now is a bit of pedagogical synergy between our answers that may prove helpful to readers.

Comment: Now its clear after your edits, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Below we show how it can be solved using more general methods for solving systems of Diophantine equations by reducing them to Hermite / Smith triangular / diagonal and related normal forms. If you search on those keywords you should find expositions on these general methods.

Below is one simple way to do so, via [this method,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) except here we need to keep track of the $3$ current rows, which are the current row plus the two notated at row end, e.g. rows $\color{#c00}{[\![5]\!]}$ snd $[\![4,2]\!]$ below.

$\ \ \ \ \begin{array}{rrrrrl}
[\![1]\!] & 437 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
[\![2]\!] & 391 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
[\![3]\!] & 323 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
[\![1]\!]-1\,[\![2]\!]\, \rightarrow\, [\![4]\!] & 46 & 1 & -1 & 0 &[\![3,2]\!]\\ 
[\![3]\!]-7\,[\![4]\!]\, \rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{[\![5]\!]} &\color{#c00}1 & \color{#c00}{{-}7} & \color{#c00}7 & \color{#c00}1& [\![4,2]\!]\ \ \ \ \ \  \smash{\overbrace{\color{#c00}1 = \color{#c00}7\cdot 437 \color{#c00}{-7}\cdot 391+\color{#c00}1\cdot 323}^{\large \color{#c00}{\text{Bezout}}\text{ Identity}}}\\ 
[\![2]\!]-8\,[\![4]\!]\, \rightarrow\, [\![6]\!] & 23 & {-}8 & 9 & 0& [\![5,4]\!]\\ 
[\![4]\!]-2\,[\![6]\!]\, \rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{[\![7]\!]} &  \color{#0a0}0 & \color{#0a0}{17} & \color{#0a0}{{-}19} & \color{#0a0}0&[\![6,5]\!]\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\text{Null$_{\:\!1}$}}\\ 
[\![6]\!]\!\!-23[\![5]\!]\, \rightarrow\,[\![8]\!] &  0 &\!\! 153 & \!\!{-}152 &\! {-}23&[\![7,5]\!]\\ 
[\![8]\!]-9\,[\![7]\!]\, \rightarrow\, \color{#90f}{[\![9]\!]} &  \color{#90f}0 & \color{#90f}0 & \color{#90f}{19} & \!\color{#90f}{{-}23} &[\![7,5]\!]\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#90f}{\text{Null$_{\:\!2}$}}\\ 
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{r r r r r l}
10473\color{#c00}{[\![5]\!]}\, \rightarrow\, [\![a]\!] & 10473 &\!\!\!-73311 &\!\! 73311 &\!\! 10473&\ \  10473\times \color{#c00}{\text{Bezout}}\text{ Identity}\\
[\![a]\!]\!-\!4313\color{#0a0}{[\![7]\!]}\, \rightarrow\, [\![b]\!] & 10473 &\!\!\!10 &\!\!\! -8636 &\!\! 10473&\ \ \text{use }\color{#0a0}{{\text {Null}}_{\:\!1}}\text{ to reduce coef of }437\\
[\![b]\!]\:\!+\:\!455\color{#90f}{[\![9]\!]}\, \rightarrow\, [\![c]\!] & 10473 &10 & 9 & 8& \ \ \text{use }\color{#90f}{{\text{Null}}_{\:\!2}}\text{ to reduce coef of }391\end{array}$

A particular solution is: $\ 10473 = 10\cdot 437 + 9 \cdot 391 + 8\cdot 323\ $ from the prior row, and

the null space is $\ (z,y,x) = (\color{#0a0}{17,-19,0})m - (\color{#90f}{0,19,-23})k = (17m,-19(m\!+\!k),23k)$

Compare robjohn's answer, which is similar, but does not explicitly use Hermite row reduction.

Comment: Thank you but I prefer your second solution given below

Comment: For another example  done this way [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338268/242)

Answer (score 0):

Three variables doesn't really make as much of a difference as you'd think.

$323 =17*19$ and $391 = 17*23$ and $437 = 19*23$

Let's suppose that $(x,y,z)$ and $(x+a, y+b, z+c)$ are two solutions to $323x + 391y + 437z = 10473$.

Then $17*19(a) + 17*23(b) + 19*23(c)= 0$ and so

$a\equiv 0 \pmod 23$, and $b\equiv 0 \pmod 19$ and $c\equiv 0 \pmod 17$

So suppose $a= 23j; b=19k; c=17m$

then we must have $j+k+m = 0$ and any such combination is possible.

So if $(x,y,z)$ is *a* solution then $(x + 23j,y+19k,z-17(j+k))$ will be a solution and that generates all solutions.

Now by Bezout we can solve $323A + 391B= 17$ and $391C + 437D = 23$ and $17M+23N = 10473$

so $(323A + 391B)M + (391C+437D)N = 10473$

and $323AM + 391(BM+CN) + 437DN = 10473$ is a solution.

So the solution set is $\{(AM+23j, BM+CN+19k, DN+17m| j+k + m = 0\}$.

.....
.....

Now was the question supposed to be that $x,y,z$ must all be positive?

If so:

$323A+391B =17$

$19A + 23B = 1$

(Argh, I really hate doing this but...)

$23 - 19 = 4$

$3 = 19-4*4 = 19 - 4(23-19) = 19*5 - 4*23$

$1 = 4-3 = (23-19)-(19*5 - 4*23) = 5*23- 6*19$

So we can let $A=-6$ and $B=5$.

$391C + 437D = 23$

$17C + 19D = 1$ so

$19 - 17 = 2$

$1=17 - 8*2 = 17- 8(19-17) = 9*17-8*19$

So we can let $C= 9$ and $D = -8$.

And for

$17M+23N = 10473$

$23 -17 = 6$

$1=3*6 - 17=3(23-17) - 17=3*23 - 4*17$

So we can let $M=-4(10473)$ and $N=3(10473)$.

So the solution set is:

$\{(AM+23j, BM+CN+19k, DN+17m| j+k + m = 0\}=$

$\{(24*10473+23j, 7*10473+19k, -24*10473+17m| j+k + m = 0\}$

To make these monster managable:

Since $24*10473, 7*10473, -24*10473$ is a solution then so is

$24*10473 - 23*2*10473, 7*10473, -24*10473 + 17*2*10473 = -22*10473,7*10473, 10*10473$ and so is

$10473, 7*10473 -19*10473, 10*10473= 10473,-125676, 104730 $ and so is

$10473, -125676+19*6615, 104730-17*6615=10473,9,-7725$ and so is

$ 10473-455*23,9, -7725+455*17= 8,9,10$

And  ... that's the only positive solution.  To have $j + k +m=0$ then one of $j,k,m \le -1$ and $8-23,9-19, 10-17$ are all negative.

Comment: I don't see any clear argument that this method yields *all* solutions of the original equation.

Comment: Doesn't it?  That yields all.... hmmm, you're right $17a+ 19a$ and $19a+ 23b$ may yield different bases and more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$323x+391y+437z=10473$$

My version of EEA is as follows.

$\begin{array}{r|r|rrr|l}
   &     & 437 & 391 & 323 \\
   \hline
   & 437 &   1 &   0 &  0 & 437-1\cdot323 = 114\\
   & 391 &   0 &   1 &  0 & 391-1\cdot323 = 68\\
   & 323 &   0 &   0 &  1 & \\
\hline
   & 323 &   0 &   0 &  1 & 323-4\cdot 68 = 51\\
   & 114 &   1 &   0 & -1 & 114 - 1\cdot 68 = 46\\
   &  68 &   0 &   1 & -1 & \\
\hline
   &  68 &   0 &   1 & -1 & 68-1\cdot 46 = 22\\
   &  51 &   0 &  -4 &  5 & 51 - 1 \cdot 46 = 5\\
   &  46 &   0 &  -1 &  1 & \\   
\hline
   &  46 &   1 &  -1 &  0 & 46 - 9\cdot 5 = 1\\
   &  22 &  -1 &   2 & -1 & 22 - 4\cdot 5 = 2\\
   &   5 &  -1 &  -3 &  5 & \\
\hline
   &   5 &   -1 &  -3 &   5 & 5-5\cdot 1 = 0\\
   &   2 &    3 &  14 & -21 & 2-2\cdot 1 = 0\\
   &   1 &   10 &  26 & -45 & \\
\hline
   &   1 &   10 &  26 & -45 & \\
   &   0 &  -51 & -133 & 230 & \text{See comments below.}\\
   &   0 &  -17 &  -38 &  69 & \\
\hline
   &   1 &   10 &  26 & -45 & \\
   &   0 &   17 & -19 &   0 & \text{See comments below.}\\
   &   0 &    0 &  19 & -23 \\
\hline
\end{array}$

Comments. The "null space" generated by the algorithm tends to be "ugly". Looking at the basis elements pairwise will give a much prettier null space.

So

$$323(-45) + 391(26) + 437(10) = 1$$

and

$$323(-471285) + 391(272298) + 437(104730) = 10473.$$

Hence

$$(x,y,z) = (-471285-23t, 272298-19s+19t, 104730+17s)$$

Comment: We can also use row operations to simplify the general solution - see the final two rows $\,[\![b]\!]$ and  $\,[\![c]\!]$ in the Remark in my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes. I did it this way at work (when I worked) because it was quick and easy to do in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for all integer solutions of

$$\tag 1 323x+391y+437z=10473$$

Using prime factorization this is equivalent to

$$ (17\cdot 19) x+(17\cdot 23)y+(19\cdot 23)z=10473$$

Applying the

$$ \pmod{23} / \pmod{19} /\pmod{17} $$

operators and solving linear congruence equations we get, respectively, that there exist integers $s, t, u \in \mathbb Z$ so that

$$ x = 8 + 23s$$
$$ y = 9 + 19t$$
$$ z = 10 + 17u$$

But the equation

$$ 323 (8 + 23 s) + 391 (9 + 19 t) + 437 (10 + 17 u) = 10473 $$

is equivalent to

$$ 7429 s + 7429 t + 7429 u = 0 $$

or

$$  s +  t + u = 0 $$

or

$$  u = -s -t $$

and so we can choose any $(s,t) \in \mathbb Z$ to determine $u$ and a solution to $\text{(1)}$.

General solution:

$$ \{ \bigr( 8+23s, 9 + 19t, 10 -17(s+t) \bigr ) \mid (s,t) \in \mathbb Z \}$$

Comment: **Note** $ $ This (ad hoc) method was already hinted in Adam's answer $4$ years ago. It exploits the very special structure of the coefficients, so will not work for general coef's (as do other answers).

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand that your mission is to close questions that, in your opinion, have been adequately answered by other responses, especially theoretical ones. I wish I could tackle other problems like this one to apply ad hoc techniques and enjoy this site.

You know, someday this site might be shut down and everyone told to direct their questions to an AI machine. How many humans will be interested in math then, when it is no fun?

Comment: Though I do participate in the important task of site moderation (esp. site *organization*) - what you wrote above is not "my mission". The main point of my above comment was to point out to readers the *relationship* between your answer and Adam's (not to discourage any particular methods).