# Solve trivariate linear Diophantine equation: $ 2x +3y +4z = 5 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, linear-diophantine-equations

This exercise is from Rosen's Elementary Number Theory:

*Solve  $ 2x +3y +4z = 5  $ in the set of integers.*

**The solution given in the book** is:

"Since $(2,3)=1$, we take $z$ to be any integer $t$ and solve the equation $2x +3y = 5-4z$, which leads to the solution $x=-5+3s-2t, y= 5-2s, z=t$.  ".

**My approach** was following:

$2x +3y = 5-4z$

Since $1= 2(-1) +3 \cdot 1 $, we have $ 5-4z = 2(-(5-4z)) + 3(5-4z) $ so particular solutions are $x_0 = -(5-4z), y_0 = 5-4z$  and then the solution is $x= (-5+4z)+3s, y= (5-4z)-2s, z=z $.

- Is my approach correct, it is different from Rosen's? If it is correct, how can be proved that they are same?
- Why $y$ in Rosen's solution does not depend on $t$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rosen has
$\begin{align} &\color{#c00}{(3,-2,0)}s\\ +\, &\color{#0a0}{(-2,0,1)}t\\ +\, &(-5,5,0)\end{align}$ vs.
$\begin{align} &(3,-2,0)s\\ +\, &\color{#90f}{(4,-4,1)}z\\ +\,&(-5,5,0)\end{align}\,$ in yours

But:  $\ 2\color{#c00}{(3,-2,0)} + \color{#0a0}{(-2,0,1)}\ \ =\ \ \color{#90f}{(4,-4,1)}\,$ so they are equivalent, i.e. the span doesn't change by the elementary row operation of adding $3$ times the first row to the second, since that's an invertible operation.

**Remark** $ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327153/242) for the general linear theory, and a formula / algorithm for the trivariate case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please answer one more question related to my method. Is it possible to apply my method to: $4x +8y +5z=1$? I get: $(4,8)=4= 1 \cdot 4 +0 \cdot 8$,  $4x +8y = 1-5z$. What should I do now? If it cannot be applied, what is the alternate method?

Comment: @user121 I think you should be able to answer this yourself if you read my linked answer, which shows the general inductive method which reduces solving an $n+1$-variable linear Diophantine equation to one with  $n$-variables (done for $\,n=3\,$ but it should be clear that the same method works generally).