# Is there a way to find the values of 3 variables with just one equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, diophantine-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, integer-partitions, linear-diophantine-equations

I was doing a personal project until I came upon this equation that i need to solve to continue, the thing is I don’t thing I have been thought this in math ever so i wonder if this even possible to solve at all if why or why not

2850=2x+4y+6z

If i can get more specific, it needs to be real numbers, and cannot be negatives, and must be only integers, no fractions. Can values aside from all real numbers be obtain with those limitations, or is it impossible?

And Thank you for thank you time to answer.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Your equation defines a plane and hence all solutions lie within that plane... which is infinite solutions. If you are looking for a particular set of solutions, you need to know the location of atleast 2 variables, or bound them in terms of each other.

Comment: If $x,y,z$   are to be non-negative integers,  there are finitely many solutions.

Comment: A linear system has a unique solution only if the number of variables is the same as the number of equation. Without more constraints, the best you can do is to express one of the variable in terms of the other 2, and you get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: You should be a bit more clear in your question about what $x,y,z$ are (even though your tags make it somewhat clear). Are they natural numbers, integers, rationals, real numbers?

Comment: Well if i can get more specific, it needs to be real numbers, and cannot be negatives, and must be only integers, no fractions. Can values aside from all real numbers be obtain with those limitations, or is it impossible?

Comment: [794ma/capacitance. Returns to what: Groundable with ammeter ac MAX discharge while open-circuited. Single line assembly around indicator and brake lights of different voltages'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H8Eu.jpg)

Comment: ... I got  *168507* solutions... Code is (in Pari/GP) `cnt=0;forstep(z6=6,2850,6,forstep(y4=4,2850-z6,4,x2=(2850-z6-y4); if(x2<2,next()); if(x2 % 2,next()); cnt++));cnt`

Comment: So $x,y,z$ are integers? Or why do you mention real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

As have been mentioned in the comments, the equation defines a plane. To 'solve' the equation, maybe you mean, what values for $x,$y provide a desired value of $z$.

I would assume that this problem qualifies to be a "Diophantine Equation".

A rigorous technique to solve such a problem, is discussed with an example in the answer of the user: robjohn in:[Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325185/find-all-the-integral-solutions-to-the-equation-323x391y437z-10473/3327153#3327153).

Assuming that you are not interested in deep theory, you can get a 'solution' either by a simple computer program with nested loops or a plot of the function in the form $z=..."$, such as the one below. Depending on the plotting tool, you can get more information about any point in the plane by a mouse click. Each positive-valued pair of $x$ and $y$ on the plane is a 'solution'. Note that the shown picture does not represent all solutions, since it is plotted in a specific range. Graphing could answer some questions one can't easily get a closed-form for sometimes.

The plot below is made for $z=(2850-2x-4y)/6$

If you have more information, for example $x+y<= 30$ for $Z=441$, in this case you could further limit the number of points that satisfies the relationship.

It may be interesting to know that there is a branch in Mathematics called "Integer Linear Programming" that deals with finding extreme value for such relationships.

The tool used is:[3-D Surface Plotter](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=(2850-2x-4y)%2F6&xRange=0%2C%2050&yRange=0%2C%2050&resolution=25)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a linear equation. That means you have a [system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations): a system of $1$ equation and $3$ variables. Because the number of variables is greater than the number of equations, the system is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system). That means the system has infinitely many solutions.

But you are asking only for the non-negative integers.
$\ $

$$2850=2x+4y+6z$$

$$1425=x+2y+3z$$

Because you are asking for non-negative integers, you are asking for [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of 1425.

You need a calculation software for that.

a)
You can use an algorithm that generates all $113072609699904337559514844445146843472$ partitions of $1425$ and write a small algorithm for extracting the wanted partitions.

b)
Here is a Maple code for generating only the wanted partitions:
$\text{n:=1425:}$
$\text{add(add(x^(n-2*j-3*k)*y^j*z^k,j=0..(n-3*k)/2),k=0..n/3);}$
Because the number of partitions is too large, you should split the command, e.g. into steps of $100$:
$\text{add(add(x^(n-2*j-3*k)*y^j*z^k,j=0..(n-3*k)/2),k=0..100);}$
$\text{add(add(x^(n-2*j-3*k)*y^j*z^k,j=0..(n-3*k)/2),k=101..200);}$
...
$\text{add(add(x^(n-2*j-3*k)*y^j*z^k,j=0..(n-3*k)/2),k=401..475);}$
You can translate that e.g. into the language of [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

c)
You can write that in a loop algorithm.
Here is a Maple code:
$\text{n:=1425:}$
$\text{for k from 0 to n/3 do}$
$\text{ for j from 0 to (n-3*k)/2 do}$
$\text{  x^(n-2*j-3*k)*y^j*z^k:}$
$\text{print(%):}$
$\text{ od:}$
$\text{od:}$
You can translate that e.g. into the language of [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: It would be nice to know how did you convert equation to a number of partitions problem and got this huge number of solutions.

Comment: @NoChance Combinatorial counting problems are different from generating problems. No closed-form expression for the unrestricted partition function is known. There are recurrence equations and power series. See Wikipedia: Partition (number theory). OEIS: A000041 https://oeis.org/A000041

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its a bit over my skill level to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume $x,y,z$ are positive integers.

$$x+2y+3z = 1425\tag{1}$$
$x+2y+3z -1425 \equiv x+z-1 \pmod{2}$, then $z=2m+1-x.$
Substitute $z=2m+1-x$ to $(1)$, then we get
$$-x+y+3m = 711$$
Let $x=n$, then we get $$y = -3m+n+711$$
Finally, $(x,y,z)=(n, -3m+n+711, 2m+1-n).$
$m,n$ are integers.
Choose $m,n$ so that $x,y,z$ are positive.