# Homogenous linear Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\dots+a_{n}x_{n}=0$ be a homogenous linear Diophantine equation on $n$ variables. Are there any conditions for this equation to have non trivial solutions? And if so, how can we calculate them?

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327153/242)