# Given $\gcd (a,b,c)=12$, find $\gcd (a,b ,c,16)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given $\gcd (a,b,c)=12$, find $\gcd (a,b ,c,16)$ I need the rule or algorithm to solve similar questions.
Is that $16 \bmod 12 = 4$ will be the new gcd of $(a,b ,c,16)$.

Comment: The fact that $16$ mod $12$ gives you the right answer is a coincidence. It would be the same answer with $16$ replaced by $20$.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$, apply multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `calculus` or with `education`?

Comment: you meen i will take the gcd( 12,16) = 4 ?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos : ops  its my first time to post

Comment: @ghadah32 I don't mean anything in particular, but if my hint is helpful, and you come up with a result, yet you still aren't sure if your calculation is right, you can write down your calculation in the question, tag this question with #proof-verification and hopefully people would be able to scrutinise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, more precisely, since [gcd is associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) we have

$$\begin {align} \gcd(a,b,c,\,16) &= \gcd(\gcd(a,b,c),\,16)\\
 &= \gcd(12,16)\\
 &= \gcd(12,\,16\bmod 12))\ \ \rm by\ Euclid\\
 &= \gcd(12,4) = 4\end{align}\qquad$$