# $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If I define $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$ be the greatest positive common divisor or $a_1,...,a_n$.

How can I show $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)$?

The equality is trivial if we have $\forall $ common divisor $c$ of $a_1,...,a_n$, $c\mid \gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$. But I think this is a consequence of the above proposition by extending the result from the case $n=2$.

It is easy to show $\gcd(\gcd(a_1,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)\le \gcd(a_1,...,a_n),$ but I got stuck showing the another side. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: GCD is not the least common divisor

Comment: edited thank you. @Raffaele

Comment: The way that I was taught number theory, if you have any two groups of positive integers [i.e. LHS denotes $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_m\}$ and RHS denotes $\{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n\}$], then the way to prove that gcd(LHS) = gcd(RHS) is to prove that any divisor of LHS is also a divisor of RHS, and vice-versa.  Assuming that you accept my methodology, the implementation with respect to the problem you posted should be straight forward.

Comment: Note that one of the *intermediate* results of number theory is (re my previous note) if $k = $ gcd{LHS} (for example), then not only is $k$ greater than any other common divisor of LHS, but any common divisor of LHS divides $k$.

Comment: how can you should $gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$ is a divisor of $gcd(a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ if without the result that $gcd(a,....,a_{n-1})$ divides any common divisor or $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$?@user2661923

Comment: by the way, if anyone think this deserve a down-vote, please help point our why it does not meet the standard.

Comment: @xyz For more on the method hinted by user2661923 see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove more generally that $D(a_1,\dots,a_n)=D(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}) \cap D(a_n)$, where $D(S)$ is the set of all positive common divisors of all elements in a set $S$. Then, by definition, $\gcd(S)=\max D(S)$. Furthermore, $D(S)=D(\gcd(S))$.

Comment: To be pedantic, $D$ takes as input sets of natural numbers, not natural numbers. Writing $D(\gcd(S))$ looks a bit strange to me. On the other hand, I'm not the intended audience for this answer post. Presumably, writing $D(\{\gcd(S)\})$ might confuse people who aren't entirely on top of this.

Comment: @Arthur, a bit of notational abuse is healthy :-) Your comment is quite right of course.

Comment: As long as there is no reasonable ambiguity, I'm all for abuse (of notation). It is, however, also healthy to be aware of when it happens

Comment: Why $D(S)=D(gcd(S))?$  i.e, why common divisors of $S$ is also a divisor of $gcd(S)?$.

Comment: By the above notation, I have $gcd(a_1,...,a_n)=max(D(a_1,...,a_{n-1})\cap D(a_n))$, But I got stuck here.

Comment: @xyz, because $\gcd(S)$ can be written as an integer linear combination of the elements of $S$.

Comment: how? I have only learnt bezout's identity for $n=2$. Is it a extension?

Comment: @xyz, exactly..

Comment: @lhf but the extension require this property asked right? is there way to prove it without this property?

Comment: @xyz, you may have a point there :-)