# Is it true that for any integer $c_1, c_2$, we have $\gcd(n_1, n_2, n_3) = \gcd(n_1, n_2, c_1 n_1 + c_2 n_2 + n_3)$ for $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I got this task to check that if $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ the $\text{gcd}(n_1, n_2, n_3) =\text{gcd}(n_1, n_2, c_1n_1 + c_2n_2 + n_3)$ is valid for any $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I started the idea saying that if:

$\text{gcd}(n_1, n_2, n_3) = k$, only if:

$k|n_1 \land k|n_2 \land k|n_3$ which means that:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
n_1=ke \\ 
n_2=kf \\
n_3=kg
\end{array}
\right. \quad e, f, g\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Now $gcd(n_1, n_2, c_1n_1 + c_2n_2 + n_3) = k$ only if:
$$ c_1n_1 + c_2n_2 + n_3 = kr, \quad r \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Substituting the values of $n_1, n_2, n_3$:
$$ k(c_1e + c_2f + g) = kr
$$
Which means that it is valid only if:$$c_1e + c_2f + g = r$$
But now I got stucked, I cannot say if this is valid for any $c_1, c_2$, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to proof that $gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=gcd(n_1,n_2,c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3)$, (not $c_3$ at the end... Who is $c_3$?)

$gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=k$;

$gcd(n_1,n_2,c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3)=p$.

$k$ divides $n_1$,$n_2$ and $n_3$.

So $k$ divides $n_1$,$n_2$,$c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3$.

So $k$ divides $p$.

But $p$ divides $n_1$,$n_2$,$c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3$. It suffices to show that $p$ divides also $n_3$. This is clear:

$n_1=ps_1$, $n_2=ps_2$, $c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3=ps_3$.

So $n_3=ps_3-c_1n_1-c_2n_2=p(s_3-c_1s_1-c_2s_2)$.

So $p$ divides $k$.

So $gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=gcd(n_1,n_2,c_1n_1+c_2n_2+n_3)$.

Comment: You are essentially reproving the gcd mod law in this special case - see my aswer.

Answer (score 1):

$${\rm RHS} =\:\! \overbrace{((n_1,n_2),\,c_1n_1\!+\!c_2n_2\!+\!n_3) = ((n_1,n_2), \color{#c00}{n_3})}^{\textstyle\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \bmod d\!=\!\color{#0a0}{(n_1,n_2)}\!:\, c_1\color{#0a0}{n_1}\!+\!c_2\color{#0a0}{n_2}\!+\!\color{#c00}{n_3}\equiv \color{#c00}{n_3} } =\:\! \rm LHS\qquad$$

via [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242): $\,(d,n,\ldots) = (d,\color{#c00}{\bar n},\ldots)\, $ if $\, n\equiv \color{#c00}{\bar n}\pmod{\!d},\,$ and  [gcd associative law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242).

Similarly a gcd stays the same if we replace any argument by any integer congruent to it mod the gcd of (some of) the *other* arguments. That's essentially  the Euclidean algorithm reduction step.

Comment: **Or** we could split it into *two* mod steps: first mod out the third arg by the first arg $n_1$ to get $\,c_2 n_2 + n_3,\,$ then mod that out by the second arg $\,n_2\,$ to get $\,n_3,\,$ ("mod out" means replace by a "simpler" congruent integer, which might not be the remainder = least congruent natural)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3943121/242)

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_1 = \gcd (n_1, n_2, n_3), d_2 = \gcd (n_1, n_2, c_1 n_1 + c_2 n_2 + n_3)$. We want to show $d_1 = d_2$.

I will prove $d_2 | d_1$. Then you can do $d_1 | d_2$ similarly then you are done.

There exists $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
x_1 n_1 + x_2 n_2 + x_3 n_3 =d_1.
$$

Therefore
$$
(x_1 - x_3 c_1) n_1 + (x_2 - x_3 c_2)n_2 + x_3 (c_1 n_1 + c_2 n_2 + n_3) =d_1 \Rightarrow d_2 | d_1.
$$

Comment: You are essentially reproving the gcd mod property in this special case - see my aswer.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!