# A basic Number-Theory related problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Suppose, $a$ and $b$ are two positive Integers such that there exist two *consecutive* positive integers $c$ and $d$ where $$a-b=a^2c-b^2d$$ We have to prove that $|a-b|$ is a perfect square.**

I tried to approach the problem in this way:

$$a-b=a^2c-b^2(c+1)\quad( \text{assuming}\;c<d)$$
$$OR,\quad b^2=(a-b)\,[c(a+b)-1]$$

Now, how do I prove that $(a-b)$ and $c(a+b)-1$ are co-prime?

Because if $ab$ is a perfect square and $(a,b)=1$, then both $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares.

Comment: We need only that all $3$ are coprime, i.e. $\,(\color{#c00}b,a\!-\!\color{#c00}b,c(a\!+\!\color{#c00}b)-1) = (b,\color{#0a0}a,c\color{#0a0}a\!-\!1) = (b,a,-1) = 1,\,$ thus $\,b^2=(a\!-\!b)\,[c(a\!+\!b)\!-\!1]\Rightarrow |a-b|$ is a square, by the Lemma in the dupe. This proof using gcds works more generally than proofs using prime factorization (and is more constructive).

Comment: In the above gcd calculation we used [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242), i.e. we can reduce all other gcd args mod one fixed arg without changing the gcd, e.g. in the first equality we reduced the 2nd & 3rd args mod the 1st arg $\,\color{#c00}b,\,$ and in the next equality we reduced the 3rd arg mod the 2nd $\,\color{#0a0}a,\,$ i.e. $\,(c\color{#0a0}a-1)\bmod \color{#0a0}a\, =\, -1.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3943121/242) for elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p \in \mathbb{P}$ be a prime number such that $p|b^2$.

Then the following are simultaneously true:
\begin{cases}
p|b \\
p|(a-b) \quad \text{or} \quad p| c(a+b)-1
\end{cases}

Now if $p|a-b$ then since $p|b$, $p$ is also divided by $a$.

Hence, $p|c(a+b)$, and thus $p \nmid c(a+b) -1$.

Thus, since $v_p(b^2)$ is even, $v_p(a-b)$ is even.

Thus $\mid a-b \mid$ is a square. $\square$

**Note** If you are not quite familiar with the notation, $v_p(x)$ is the power of prime $p$ in the prime representation of $x \in \mathbb{Z+}$. But that is quite unnecessary in this case. You can deduce that $\gcd(a-b, c(a+b)-1)=1$ anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

If a prime $p$ divides $a-b$, then  since
$$  b^2=(a-b)\,[c(a+b)-1] \,,$$
we deduce that $p$ also divides $b$. Thus $p$ divides $a+b=a-b+2b$,
so it cannot divide $ c(a+b)-1 $.