# In an Integral Domain is it true that $\gcd(ac,ab) = a\gcd(c,b)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

In my algebra class I was given as homework assignment to prove that:

> Given an integral domain $A$ and $a,b,c,d,e \in A$. Then if $d = \gcd(b,c)$ and $e = \gcd(ac, ab)$ then $e = ad$.

It is easy to see that $ad \mid ab$ and $ad \mid ac$, so this implies that $\exists q \in A; e = q(ad)$.
Now I'm having problems showing that $q = 1_A$. Working through some equalities, I proved that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, q^n \mid d$ so this gives me the light suspicion that I might be going the right way, but I'm pretty positive that this does not imply $q = 1_A$.

Does anyone want to give me a hint?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are integral domains in which there are no g.c.d. s. Yoy need a `gcd domain`( (for instance a UFD or a PID).

Comment: @Bernard I am aware of that, but in this case the problem states that the element $e$ is indeed a gcd of $ac$ and $ab$. There's no problem with the extistence there

Comment: See the 2nd proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

Set $\;b=b'd$, $\;c=c'd\;\;$ ($b'\wedge c'=1$), $\;ab=\beta e$, $\;ac=\gamma e\;\;$ ($\beta\wedge\gamma=1$). We have:
\begin{align*}
q\beta e&=qab=qadb'=eb',\\
q\gamma e& =qac=qadc'=ec',
\end{align*}
whence, since $A$ is a domain, $\;b'=q\beta,\enspace c'=q\gamma$. As $b'\wedge c'=1$, these relations imply $q$ is a unit.

Comment: what does $b' \wedge c' = 1$ mean?

Comment: Another notation for the g.c.d. of $b'$ and $c'$.

Comment: How do you know that the gcd of $b'$ and $c'$ exists?

Comment: They have to be coprime if $d$ is the g.c.d. of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I get it, it was not hard to prove that. I guess I am just new to all of this. I wasn't aware of that fact. Thanks Bernard :)