# If $d$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$, is $dx$ a gcd of $ax$ and $bx$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

Let $D$ be an **integral domain** and $a,b,x \in D$.

If $d$ is a greatest common divisor ( gcd ) of $a$ and $b$, is it true that $dx$ is a gcd of $ax$ and $bx$?

Note that $D$ is an integer domain, not a GCD domain. So this question is not the same as any of the following questions：[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1932541/556437) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1725148/556437) [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202397) etc. More specifically, the existence of gcd of $ax$ and $bx$ is not guaranteed.

Any insights are much appreciated.

BTW: To avoid [ambiguity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4229910/556437), I haven't used notations such as $(a,b)$ or $(ax,bx)$, which makes me verbose. You may use it at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take $D=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, $a=2,b=1+1\sqrt{-5},x=3$. Using the norm we see that $d=1$ is a gcd of $a,b$. However, $3d=3$ is not a gcd of $ax=6$ and $bx=3+3\sqrt{-5}$. This is because $1+\sqrt{-5}\mid ax,bx$ but $1+\sqrt{-5}\nmid 3$. (consequently $ax$ and $bx$ don't have a gcd.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is important.

Comment: Excuse me, may I ask one more question? Why do you say that $ax$ and $bx$ don't have a gcd? I know that $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are not gcds of  $6$ and $3+3\sqrt{-5}$. But maybe other elements? Thank you.

Comment: @SkysubO the questions/answers you linked in your question shows that *if* $ax$ and $bx$ have a gcd, *then* it has to be (up to units) $dx$. But here $dx=3$ is not a gcd of $ax$ and $bx$, hence they cannot have a gcd. One can also see this directly: suppose they had a gcd $e$. By taking norms we would have $N(e)\mid 18$ and $9,6\mid N(e)$ (because $e\mid ax,bx$ and $3, 1+\sqrt{-5}\mid e$). But then $N(e)=18$ and you can verify that there is no solution to $N(e)=18$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Ah, I see. The first way is ingenious. Thank you very much!