# If $\gcd(a,b)\sim 1$, $\gcd(a,c)\sim1$, then $\gcd(a,bc)\sim1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain, coprime

In **integral domains**, prove or give a counterexample：

> If $(a,b)\sim 1$, $(a,c)\sim1$, then $(a,bc)\sim1$.

That is to say, if $a,\,b$ are relatively prime and $a,\,c$ are relatively prime, then $a,\,bc$ are relatively prime.

Note that it needn't be a GCD domain. So usual proofs may not work here.

Any insights are much appreciated.

BTW："$(a,b)$" is the abbreviation for "$\gcd(a,b)$" and "$x\sim y$" denotes the statement that $x$ and $y$ are associates. In integral domains, a gcd is often not unique when it exists. So "$(a,b)$" here denotes an **arbitrary** gcd of a and b. For the same reason, we use "$\sim$ " instead of "$=$".

Comment: For a counterexample, my initial guess would be to take $a = 2$, $b = 1 - \sqrt{-5}$, $c = 1 + \sqrt{-5}$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Comment: What do you denote $(a,b)\sim 1$?

Comment: Integral domains don’t even necessarily have a notion of GCD. (Presumably, that is what you mean by $(a,b)$)

Comment: If by $(a,b)\sim 1$ you mean the ideal generated by $a,b$ is the whole ring $R$ (i.e., $(a)$ and $(b)$ are coprime ideals), then $R=aR+bR=aR+b(aR+cR)=aR+bcR$.

Comment: @Bernard 1 is a $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$, in other words,  $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the post.  It means $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: If you simply mean there exists $u,v,u',v'$ in the integral domain such that $ua+vb=1$ and $u'a+v'c=1$, you just have to multiply these relations.

Comment: @SkysubO You still haven't define what you mean by coprime in this context.  There are two inequivalent definitions of "$a,b$ coprime" you can use: (1) There are no common divisors other than units (2) the principal ideals are coprime ideals $aR+bR=R$.  (2) implies (1) but not the other way round, e.g. $x+2$ and $x+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @user10354138 Ah, I see. I mean $1$ is a $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$, that is,  (1) There are no common divisors other than units

Comment: @Bernard Unfortunately, we don't have the equation $ua+vb=1$. Let $d$ be a gcd of $a$ and $b$. Generally in integral domains, we only have $(a)+(b)\subseteq(d)$. So here we just know $(a)+(b)\subseteq(1)$.

Comment: @SkysubO: However, your ring is a gcd domain?

Comment: @Bernard Just an integral domain.  If it's a gcd domain, the statement is true.

Comment: What does ‘coprime’ mean in this  case?

Comment: ‘coprime’ means  $1$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$, in other words, $a$ and $b$ have no common divisors except units.

Comment: @Rushy Sounds a good idea! Can you prove that $\gcd(\,2\ , 1-\sqrt{-5})\sim 1$ ?

Comment: They are irreducible, so either $(2, 1 - \sqrt{-5}) \sim 1$ or $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{5}$ are associate. But the only units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]$ are $1$ and $-1$, so they aren't associates.

Comment: @Rushy I'm sure they are all irreducible and the fact that $2$ and $1−\sqrt{-5}$  are not associates.  So my only concern or question is the statement "either...or...".

Comment: Assume that $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ have a common divisor $d$, i.e. we have $2 = ad$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}= bd$. Either $d$ is a unit, or we have that $d$ is not a unit, in which case both $a$ and $b$ must be units due to irreducibility of $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$. But then $ba^{-1}$ is a unit and $ba^{-1} \cdot 2 = ba^{-1}ad = bd = 1-\sqrt{-5}$, so $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ are associates.

Comment: And since the only associates of $2$ are $2$ and $-2$, we conclude that $d$ must be a unit and the claim follows.

Comment: @Rushy Nice proof, your are great! Such a good counterexample is beyond my expectation.  I thought before that the counterexample should be something where $\gcd(a,bc)$ doesn't exist.  Please write it as a formal answer to let more people know. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false. As a counterexample, consider $a = 2$, $b = 1 - \sqrt{-5}$ and $c = 1 + \sqrt{-5}$ in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Note that $a, b,$ and $c$ are irreducible.

We show that $(2, 1 - \sqrt{-5}) \sim 1$. Assume that $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ have some common divisor $d$. Then we can write $2 = xd$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5} = yd$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. If $d$ is not a unit, then we have by irreducibility of $a$ and $b$ that $x$ and $y$ are units. But then $yx^{-1}$ is a unit and we find that $yx^{-1}\cdot 2 = yx^{-1}xd = yd = 1 - \sqrt{-5}$, i.e. $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ are associate elements. This is a contradiction, since the only units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ are $1$ and $-1$, hence the only elements associate to $a = 2$ are $2$ and $-2$.

Thus we can conclude that $(2, 1 - \sqrt{-5}) \sim 1$, and by the same argument $(2, 1 - \sqrt{-5}) \sim 1$. However, $bc = (1 - \sqrt{-5})(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = 6$, so $(a, bc) = (2, 6)$. Clearly $2$ and $6$ have $2$ as a common divisor, so $(a, bc) \nsim 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a **wrong** proof here to show that how deceptive this claim is. Even textbook authors were deceived and accepted it as a lemma. Please see the picture below:

[image: wrong proof]

$(1)$ is the proposition sometimes called the **GCD Distributive Law**. Since there are  better [proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202403/556437) for it, I've omitted the proof of $(1)$ in the translation：

> **Lemma** $\quad$Let $R$ be an integral domain, $a,b,c\in R-\left\{0 \right\}$. Then
>
> $(1)$ $\ \ c\,(a,b)\sim (ca,cb)$.
>
> $(2)$ $\ \ (a,b)\sim 1$, $(a,c)\sim1$, then $(a,bc)\sim 1$.
>
> **Proof** $\quad(1)$ ...
>
> $(2)$ From $(a,b)\sim 1$ and $(1)$ we know that $(ac,bc)\sim c$, and
> obviously we have $(a,ac)\sim a$. So $(a,bc)\sim ((a,ac),bc)\sim$
> $(a,(ac,bc))\sim (a,c)\sim 1$. QED

However, $(2)$ is false because of the answer by Rushy. What's wrong with the proof ?

Note that the GCD Distributive Law $(1)$ requires that $(ca,cb)$ exists in R (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240437)). But the proof of $(2)$ employs $(1)$ without guaranteeing the existence of $(ac,bc)$. Therefore the statement "$(ac,bc)\sim c$" is incorrect. Consequently, the proof is wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community OK. I've updated the answer.