# GCD in unique factorization domain

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

Let be D a unique factorization domain, k in D and $x=kd $ with $d$ a gcd of $a, b$ and $y$ a gcd of $ka, kb$ prove that x and y are associates; x divides y and y divides x.
My attempt:

x=kd and a=dr, b=ds hence ka=kdr, kb=kds so ka=xr, kb=xs hence x divides y because y is gcd of ka and kb.

How to prove that y divides x?

Comment: since $d=\gcd(a,b)$ there are $s$ and $t$ such that $d=sa+tb$; if $y=\gcd(ka,kb)$ , then  $y$ divides $ka$ and $kb$ and therefore $ska+tkb=kd=x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner There is no Bézout theorem in UFDs.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that $(ma, mb) = |m|(a, b)\ $ \[GCD Distributive Law\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705862/prove-that-ma-mb-ma-b-gcd-distributive-law)

Comment: See the linked dupe for a few proofs.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path:  you mean in non-Euclidean UFDs

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you very much

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Technically, I mean in non-Bézout-domain UFDs.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path:  I stand corrected again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ k\mid (ka,kb)\mid ka,kb\,\Rightarrow\, (ka,kb)/k\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,(ka,kb)/k\mid (a,b)\,\Rightarrow\,(ka,kb)\mid k(a,b)$

**Remark** $ $ In fact the proof can be done more efficienitly *bidirectionally* as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705862/prove-that-ma-mb-ma-b-gcd-distributive-law).