# Find n where $GCD(a_{n}, 14) = 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The question was:

- Find $n$ where $GCD(a_{n}, 14) = 7$ where $n$ is natural if you knew that $a_{n} = n + 3$

The book solved it by saying that means $a_{n}$ is a multiple of $7$ but not $14$ so $a_{n} = 7a$ and by putting it in the equation

$GCD(7a, 14) = 7$ means $GCD(a,2) = 1$ which means $a = 2k + 1$ and by putting it in $a_{n}$ we find that n = 14a + 4$

The first, I understand that because if it was a multiple of 14 then we would take $14$ as the $GCD$ not $7$

What I didn't understand is that what putting $a_{n} = 7a$ has anything to do with not being a multiple of 14? 14 can be written as $7(2)$ which means $a_{n}$ can be clearly a multiple of 14 too.

Comment: Use `\gcd` for $\gcd$, or, if you really want to use capital letters, use `\operatorname{GCD}` for $\operatorname{GCD}$, though this is less common.

Comment: My guess would be that they mean $a_n=7a$ with odd $a$. But that's something they should -say-, not leave to your imagination. (Myself I'd write $a_n=14b+7$. That's the same if you write $a=2b+1$ but makes $a$ explicitly odd.)

Comment: It is clearly intended that $a_n$ expressible in the form $(7a)$ is a **necessary** condition.  This is how you take a 1st step in attacking the problem.  The next step would be to refine the constraint by **further** specifying that $a$ is odd.  The **mis**interpretation that you encountered was that you took the constraint $a_n = 7a$ out of context and misinterpreted it as intending that the constraint (in addition to being necessary) was also sufficient.

Comment: If $a_n$ is a multiple of $14$, then $GCD(a_{n}, 14) = 14$.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you quote that $GCD(7a, 14) = 7$ means the same as  $GCD(a, 2) = 1$ and therefore $a=2k+1$ is correct.

You therefore know that $$n+3=7a=7(2k+1)=14k+7.$$

Then $n=14k+4$, as required

Answer (score 0):

The proof is incorrect / incomplete since it gives only a *necessary* condition for $n$ to be a solution. To fix it you either need to check that the candidate $n$ works or else verify that all inferences are actually *bidirectional* (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20unidirectional) for more on the insufficiency of unidirectional inferences). Let's do the proof with bidirectional inferences, which will answer your question along the way.

First, $7$ is a common *divisor* of $\,n+3\,$ and $\,14,\,$ thus a divisor of $\,n+3,\,$ i.e. $\,\color{#0a0}{7\mid n+3},\,$ Using this and $\, 7x = (7y,7z)\color{#c00}\iff x = (y,z)\,$ by  $\rm\color{#c00}{GDL}$ = [gcd distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) we have

$$\begin{align} 7 = (n+3,14) &\iff \ \ \color{#0a0}{7\mid n+3}\ \ \ \ \ \&\ \ \ 7 = (n+3,\ \ 14)\\[.1em]
&\iff n=4+7k\ \ \ \&\ \ \ 7 = (7+7k,\:\!14)\\[.1em]
&\color{#c00}\iff n=4+7k\ \ \ \&\ \ \ 1 = (1+k,\ 2)\ \ \ \rm by\ \color{#c00}{GDL}\\[.1em]
&\iff n=4+7k\ \ \ \&\ \ \ k = 2j\\[.1em]
&\iff n = 4+7(2j) 
\end{align}\qquad$$