# Proving $(ax,bx)=x(a,b)$ using THIS method

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

**This isn't a duplicate! the "duplicate" question doesn't use my method of proof but other methods and I made it clear that I want this method in specific.**

I want to prove the following claim using the following method.

$(ax,bx)=x(a,b)$

What I have done so far:

let's call $(a,b)$ by $d$, then:

$d|a, d|b$ so $xd|ax, xd|bx$ then $xd|(ax,bx)$

How can I continue from here? I didn't prove equality...

Comment: You used the common divisor part of $(a,b)$ to get the common divisor part of $(ax,bx)$. Now use the greatest part of $(a,b)$ to figure the greatest part of $(ax,bx)$.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith sorry I didn't understand anything from what you wrote... I need to prove equality not GCD

Comment: The equality you are trying to prove is about GCD, correct? There are two things needed for an integer to be the GCD: it must be a common divisor and it must be the greatest. You have proved that $x(a,b)$ is indeed a common divisor of $ax$ and $bx$. You will have equality once you show it is the greatest.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith thanks it's clear now and that's what I tried to do but failed :(

Comment: @zoro Welcome to MSE! What do you mean by "failed" with Aaron's method? That is to say, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @EricSnyder dead end.

Comment: The claim in your edit is false - the first "Theorem" in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) in the dupe gives a divisibility based proof continuing that in your question. Most of the common proofs are there.

Comment: @BillDubuque it's not even clear what he's trying to prove. Sorry I'm not professor in mathematics. I'm looking for easy to understand method just like what I started...

Answer (score -1):

Continue on by writing out $xd\mid (xa,xb)$ as an equation and see what this says about the integers $\frac{(xa,xb)}{x}$, $a$, and $b$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).